# Why use defer with Google Maps Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, deferred

The Google Maps javascript does some heavy DOM manipulation. Even so, [the fine docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) suggest to load it with the `defer` flag:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Why would the `defer` flag be suggested for a script that performs DOM manipulations? **I ask to learn both about the `defer` flag and to learn about the Google Maps API** as I seem to have a misunderstanding about what one of them is doing.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Normally, a `script` tag tells the browser to stop parsing the HTML, fetch the script, run it, and only then continue parsing the HTML. This is because the script code may use `document.write` to output to the HTML token stream.

[`async` and `defer`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-defer) are both mechanisms for telling the browser that it's okay to go ahead and keep parsing the HTML in parallel with downloading the script file, and to run the script file later, not right away.

They slightly different, though; this diagram from [the `script` section](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#attr-script-async) of the WHAT-WG version of the HTML spec is useful for envisioning the differences:

[image]

Full details in the linked spec above, but in brief, for "classic" scripts (the kind you're used to; but module scripts are coming soon!):

- Both `async` and `defer` allow the parsing of the HTML to continue without waiting for the script to download.
- `defer` will make the browser wait to execute the script until the parsing is complete.
- `async` will only make the browser wait until the script download is complete, which means it may run the script either before parsing is complete or afterward, depending on when download finishes (and remember it could come from cache).
- If `async` is present and supported by the browser, it takes precedence over `defer`.
- `async` scripts may be run in any order, regardless of the order in which they appear in the HTML.
- `defer` scripts will be run in the order they appear in the HTML, once parsing is complete.
- `async` and `defer` are well-supported in even semi-modern browsers, but are not properly supported in IE9 and earlier, see [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=script-async) and [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=script-defer).

> Why would the `defer` flag be suggested for a script that performs DOM manipulations?

Two reasons:

1. It allows the parsing to continue while the script is downloaded, and
2. It means the script isn't run until parsing is complete.

If you didn't use `defer` and you placed your `script` tags non-optimally, using `defer` helps the API script behave properly by letting the browser finish building the DOM before the script tries to manipulate it.

A lot of people still put `script` tags in the `head` section of the document, even though that's usually the worst place to put them *unless* you use `defer` (or `async`). In most cases, the best place (unless you have a reason to do something else) is at the very *end*, just before the closing `</body>` tag, so that A) Your site renders quickly, without waiting for scripts; and B) The DOM is fully built before you try to manipulate it. Recommending `defer` may be saving them support hassles from people putting their `script` tags too early in the HTML.

Comment: I think that I see. So it seems that [the article](http://www.sitepoint.com/non-blocking-async-defer/) which I read to understand the defer and async attributes is **completely wrong**, and even **contradicts the spec**. Shame that it ranks so [highly on Google](https://google.com/?q=javascript+defer+async).

Comment: @dotancohen: No, it's correct, it's just a bit vague when it says "...does not contain any document.write or DOM modification nastiness:". What it *should* say is something like "...does not contain any document.write or DOM modifications meant to be run inline with the parser." (since there are other things you can do, not just `document.write`, which would rely on the parser being held up waiting for your script to run). It shouldn't have given the impression **all** DOM modifications were off the table.

Answer (score 3):

The google maps examples use both `async` and `defer` flags.

- The `async` flag allows the script to load in parallel to the DOM
  parsing, and to execute as soon as the API is ready.
- The `defer` flag allows the script to load in parallel to the DOM
  parsing, but guarantees that the script will not execute until the
  DOM is finished parsing.

`async` is supported by modern HTML5 browsers, while `defer` support is universal. When the tags are used together, **`defer` is just a fallback for older browsers, and will be ignored if `async` is supported**.

In these simple examples, either `async` or `defer` will work, though neither are necessary. In this case it's for performance only.

Refs:
[Speed up Google Maps(and everything else) with async & defer](https://medium.com/@nikjohn/speed-up-google-maps-and-everything-else-with-async-defer-7b9814efb2b)
[async vs defer attributes - Growing with the Web](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2014/02/async-vs-defer-attributes.html)