# how to set react typescript useState fetch type and using map method

Tags: reactjs, typescript, async-await, react-typescript

currently i'm practice react-ts fetching json data via async fetcher

sample code is below like this

```
//Test.tsx
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import fetcher from 'api/fetcher';

interface Todo {
  userId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  completed: boolean;
}

const Test: React.FC = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<Todo[]| Promise<Todo[]>>([{
    userId: 1,
    id: 1234,
    title: "test",
    completed: false
  }]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const result = fetcher("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos");
    setData(result);
    console.log(result);
  }, [])
  return (
    <div>
      //error in here
      **{data && data.map()}**
        {/* {data && data.map((item: Todo)=> {
          <div>{item.id}<div>
        })} */}
  </div>
  );
}
export default Test;
```

```
//fetcher.ts
async function fetcher(url: RequestInfo) {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(url);
    const json = await res.json();
    console.log("json: ", json);
    return json;
  } catch (e) {
    throw e;
  }
}

export default fetcher;
```

**Error Message :
Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Todo[] | Promise'.
 Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Promise'**

i know map method can't using at Promise Object. due to async call, initial data type is set to be Promise type, and switched to Todo[] when fetch resolved.

how to solve this problem to use map method dynamically

Comment: You'll need to `await` the call to `fetcher` in order to get your todo list out of the promise. Try using the method suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56838577/2178159) in your `useEffect`.

Comment: Comment 1 is right and should be marked as the answer. Using `useState<Todo[]>` will fix this specific error.

Comment: @CameronLittle  i had forgotten to reply.. sry and thx all of u

Comment: @bastianwegge thx!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not set the promise to state instead set the result obtained after promise is resolved. To wait for promise to resolve you can make use of `async-await` or `conventional .then` method. Also remove Promise as a type from useState value

```
const Test: React.FC = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<Todo[]>([{
    userId: 1,
    id: 1234,
    title: "test",
    completed: false
  }]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetcher("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos").then((result) => {
        setData(result);
    });
  }, [])
  return (
    <div>
        {data && data.map((item: Todo)=> {
          <div>{item.id}<div>
        })}
  </div>
  );
}
export default Test;
```