# REACT Typescript fetch/ axios error - following properties from type 'Address[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more. TS2740

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, fetch

```
import {Address} from './address.model';
export const get = async ():Promise<Address[]>    =>  {  
  
  return await fetch(`${apiUrl}`)
  .then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(response.statusText)
    }
    return   response.json() as Promise<Address[]>;
  })

//--------------caling from
 React.useEffect(() => {
    let newArr: Address[] = get()  ;
     setEntities(newArr);
  } , [])
```

//-------------throws following error:
Type 'Promise<Address[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'Address[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more.  TS2740

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the problematic casting (*cf*. `as Promise<Address[]>`) you'll need to await your `get()` function to get the `Address[]` type, so

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
    async get() => {
     // do the IO
    }
    const newArr: Address[] = await get()
    setEntities(newArr)
  } , [])
```

Comment: Good point. But adding async throws following error:

Argument of type '() => Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EffectCallback'.
  Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'void | (() => void | undefined)'.
    Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '() => void | undefined'.
      Type 'Promise<void>' provides no match for the signature '(): void | undefined'.  TS2345

Comment: async inside useEffect need to like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56838392/how-to-call-an-async-function-inside-a-useeffect-in-react . I'll go ahead make change in the answer.

Comment: Ah yes, I always make this mistake. I'll update my code block to match for the next person.