# Fetch is still pending in react api call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component. If I user clicks on a Link To on the parent component they land on this child componented just fine. However if they refresh the page, or go to the link directly, their is no data, so I need to make an api call again myself for that unique id.

When I make the api call (when issue is undefined), it works, but I get a promise back that has fulfilled, with no data. How do I get the object?

```
class Issue extends React.Component {
       

            getIssue = async (id) => {
                try {
                    const endpoint = `https://api.github.com/repos/facebook/create-react-app/issues/${id}`;
                    const response = await fetch(endpoint);
                    const data = await response.json();
                    return data;
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            }
        
    
        // }
        render(){
            
            let { issue } = this.props.location;
            console.log(issue);
    
            if(issue === undefined){
                console.log('No Data');
                issue = this.getIssue(this.props.match.params.id);
                console.log(issue);
            } else {
                console.log('Data');
            }
    
            return (
            <h1>ff</h1>
                
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: if issue is undifined render a loading component . and make ur api call in componentDidMount()

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Do you see a valid id if you `console.log(id)` before your `try` in your  `getIssue` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite your component to use state, rewrite `getIssue` to use [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) (it fits better here) and move it to `componentDidMount` method.

```
class Issue extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const id = this.props.match.params.id;
    const endpoint = `https://api.github.com/repos/facebook/create-react-app/issues/${id}`;

    fetch(endpoint)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ data }))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  render() {
    return <h1>{this.state.data ? this.state.data.title : "Loading..."}</h1>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because your `getIssue()` is `async` function and it will return a promise which you have to handle later on. In your `render()` method you are not doing it, you have to use `getIssue()` with `then()` chained where you can get your data from promise:

```
render() {
  let { issue } = this.props.location;
  console.log(issue);

  if(issue === undefined) {
    console.log('No Data');
    this.getIssue(this.props.match.params.id)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
      });
  } else {
    console.log('Data');
  }
  
  return (
    <h1>ff</h1>
  )
}
```

Comment: The OP says that "I get a promise back that has fulfilled, with no data", so it seems like they know that `getIssue` is returning a promise, it's just that it doesn't resolve with any data... (I could be misinterpreting the issue though)

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking exactly the same about misinterpreting now :) There's plenty of answers already, I hope one will be correct...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call async functions during `render()`
You should do async calls on a `useEffect` hook (if using hooks) or `componentDidMount` or one of the lifecycles of a React class.

An example:

```
class Issue extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      issue: null
    }
       
  componentDidMount() {
    const { issue } = this.props.location;
    if (!issue) {
      getIssue(this.props.match.params.id).then(data => {
        this.setState({ issue: data });
       }
    }
            
     getIssue = async (id) => {
                try {
                    const endpoint = `https://api.github.com/repos/facebook/create-react-app/issues/${id}`;
                    const response = await fetch(endpoint);
                    const data = await response.json();
                    return data;
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            }
        
    
        // }
        render(){
            
            let { issue } = this.state;
            console.log(issue);
    
            return (
            <h1>ff</h1>
                
            )
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Two issues :

1. Fetch usage - Just use the direct result and not the data as follows:

```js
const url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/facebook/create-react-app/issues/20'

const getData = async () => {
  const data = await fetch(url);
  console.log(data)
}

getData();
```

2. Using async in `useEffect` or `componentDidMount` - To use in `useEffect` you can refer this: [How to call an async function inside a UseEffect() in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56838392/how-to-call-an-async-function-inside-a-useeffect-in-react)