# ReactJs .map in data received by api

Tags: reactjs, api

and thank you in advance for any help.
I am trying to build a web app that fetches data from an API, in this case a movie database API, but when i am trying to map all the movies from a specific title search i get the **.map is not a function error**, what i am doing wrong ? Can't i use useState to display the data ?
When i do console.log (search) i can see the array with all the data :

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


export default function RandomFacts() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');
  const [search, setSearch] = useState(['']);

  useEffect(() => {
    apiCall();
  }, [input]);

  const moviesList = search && search.map((movie, index) =>
    <div className="movies" key="index">
      <li><h2>{movie.Title}</h2></li>
      <li><img src={movie.Poster} alt="poster" /></li>
    </div>,
  );

  const apiCall = async () => {
    const url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?s='+input+'&page=1&apikey=536a34c3';

    try {
      const response = await axios.get(url);
      if (response.status === 200 && response !== undefined) {
        const data = response.data;
        setSearch(data.Search);
        console.log(search);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };


  return (
    <div className="main">
      <h1>Movies</h1>
      <div className="textInput">
        <form>
          <label>
            <input type="text" value={input}
              onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
            />
          </label>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div className="movies">
        {moviesList}
      </div>

    </div>

  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share a console log of response? I’m assuming it’s an object with a data key that contains the array. So you’d need to change the setSearch to use res.data.

Comment: Thanks for the help, edited the code, it had some errors, but the error it's still happening.
Added the console.log

Comment: That's helpful! `data` was just a guess, I can see that you want `Search`.

Comment: You need to see whats happening in the response, i recommend adding properties one by one to find the bug, whenever you get this error `.map is not a function error,` is because you are traying to use a array method in a non array value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API is returning a `response` Object with a `data` key containing the keys `Search`, `TotalResults`, and `Response`. You're trying to map this `response` Object instead of the Array contained in `response.data.Search`.

So you should be using `setSearch(response.data.Search)`.

Comment: I used your idea and with a little fiddling i got it to work. Thank you very much.
But i am struggling with another issue, the output does not match the input exactly, 
for example, if i search for Queen it only searches for Quee, only if write Queenn do i get the result for Queen, i believe it's some issue with useState when declaring  const [input, setInput] = useState(""), but i have tried several things and i can't get it to work.

Comment: You're making the API call before the state had a chance to update `input`. There's no reason to store `input` in state in this case, why don't you just make the API call directly in the `onChange` instead of `setInput`? A better/advanced approach would be to use `useEffect` to make an API call whenever `state.input` changes.

Comment: I am going the right way ? At least i tried it and it's updating input correctly, but i can't pass the if in useEffect, it's always returning undefined...

Comment: yea i think that should work. `status` isn't returned in the `response` object in this case (look at your console log). Try checking if `response && response.Response === 'True'` or you can try `response?.Response === 'True'` if your babel config supports `?`. Also you don't want to use `response.data` - we said `response.Search`.

Comment: Tried both and still not getting pass the if. Used a couple console.log(input) just before the if, and everything runs great, the input variable is updated correctly.

Comment: Could be because of the async ?

Comment: Yea you're right about the async, good catch. Try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56838577/4722345).

Comment: Worked !! Changed the code in the original post for future reference in case someone gets in same trouble.Thank you very much for the help . It's for people like you that stackoverflow rules !

Comment: Great! Given that I solved the original issue with the map not working, do you mind accepting + giving an upvote? 

Comment: Sorry, i thought i had done it before, but i haven't, did it now. 
Unfortunately it does not accept my upvote because i have less than 15 points reputation... :(