# How to fetch a data without using useffect or setTimeout and add loader in react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

***DETAIL****

```
const Detail = (props) {

    const { getLatest, getAll } = useRoom();
    const [ rowData, setRowData ] = useState([]);
    const [ state, setState ] = useState([]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            getLatest(PARAMS).then((res) => setState(res['data'].data));
            getAll({length: 9999}).then((res) => setRowData(res['data'].data));
        }
        fetchData();
    }, []);

     return (
{state &&
                state.map((res, i) => (
                    <div key={i} className="w-full px-2 flex rounded justify-center items-center p-2 m-1 bg-white">
                        <Room item={res}  />
                    </div>
                ))}
    )
    }
    
export default Detail;
```

What I'm trying to do here is to add a loader also my problem is when I didn't use the setTimeout I'm getting error which is `Request failed with status code 500`. but when I added the setTimeout there's no error.

```
setTimeout(() => {...fetchData }
```

***API CALLING***

```
getLatest: (params?: object) => Axios.get(`${API_URL}/latest` + (params ? getQueryParams(params) : ''))
```

HERE's the error when reload the page.
[image]

Comment: Because you are aborting the HTTP requests before they complete and your server doesn't know how to deal with an abort signal. So the `setTimeout()` is allowing the HTTP request to complete and prevents the abort. **Answer**: Don't abort the HTTP request.

Comment: @RandyCasburn So the solution, is to add the ```setTimeout()```? is there other way fetch a data without using the setTimeout? I remove the ```abortController```.

Comment: Does this **accepted answer** answer your question? [How to call an async function inside a UseEffect() in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56838392/how-to-call-an-async-function-inside-a-useeffect-in-react)

Comment: @RandyCasburn same error

Comment: Then the request to being malformed elsewhere. that code has not been provided in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You're not really doing anything with the `async` function. The point of using an `async` function is that you use `await` inside to wait for the server's response. Try using `await` instead of using `then` with the requests that you're making to the server. I believe something like this will work:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        let res = await getLatest(PARAMS);
        setState(res['data'].data)
        let resAll = await getAll({length: 9999});
        setRowData(resAll['data'].data)
    }
    fetchData();
}, []);
```

Comment: the error still exist when reload the page

Comment: Maybe it might be best to get some info about your backend. The request might not be related to the async function. The set timeout delays the HTTP request so there is something that might need to happen before you send the HTTP request. If there is a way you can get an error log of the backend (since it's a status code 500), it will help you resolve the issue.

Comment: I tried to see if it can be a frontend issue. Take a look at this, it's something similar to your problem. I hope it helps! https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1143#issuecomment-340331822