# How come UseState sometimes works sometimes doesn't in my code

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, ethereum, web3js

I am getting a strange behaviour from React useEffect and useState hooks: 7-8 times out of 10 it doesn't set vaults and it keeps having an empty object, while 2-3 times out of ten it does set it.

I am getting some data from the binance testnet blockchain correctly (console logs all log the right data each time, never get undefined) but when I am saving the data into vaults using useState, sometimes it saves it into vaults, sometimes it doesn't.

Somehow, sometimes (very few times) SetVault works and set vaults with the result from the blockchain, sometimes (most of the times) it just doesn't set anything.

Any idea on what is happening?

Code:

```
 const [vaults, setVaults] = useState({});

 useEffect(() => {
    async function loadBloackchainData() {
      const web3 = new Web3('https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545/');
      const vault = new web3.eth.Contract(VaultABI, testnet.Vaults[0].address);
      const name = await vault.methods.symbol().call();
      console.log('name: ', name);  // ok data is logged correctly
      const totalSupply = parseInt(await vault.methods.totalSupply().call());
      console.log('totalSupply: ', totalSupply); // ok data is logged correctly
      const totalBorrowed = parseInt(await vault.methods.vaultDebtVal().call());
      console.log('totalBorrowed: ', totalBorrowed); // ok data is logged correctly
      const capUtilRate = Number.isNaN(totalSupply / totalBorrowed) ? 0 : totalSupply / totalBorrowed;
      console.log('capUtilRate: ', capUtilRate); // ok data is logged correctly

      // ALL GOOD TILL HERE

      setVaults(vaults => ({
        ...vaults,
        [name]: {
           totalSupply,
           totalBorrowed,
           capUtilRate,
        },
      }));
      console.log('vaults inside useffect: ', vaults); // {}
    }

    loadBloackchainData();
  }, []);
  console.log('vaults outside useffect: ', vaults); // {}
```

Comment: You doubt is the last console.log working incorrectly?

Comment: that and also outer console.logs, outside the useEffect also log empty object

Comment: This probably isn't the solution but because you are calling this useEffect on mount, you probably can just setVaults to the object rather than getting the previous data and merging that with the new object

Comment: That I did because I need to loop through an array and create multiple objects inside vaults. I didn'add the array loop to not add unnecessary complexity

Comment: Could you try building the object before hand and then consoling it before setting the state and see if that is working 100% of the time.

Comment: Just tried that too. No luck, sorry

Comment: Then that is telling me that the issue isn't to do with your setState but all the stuff that is happening before it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting state variable doesn't run immediately as you are expecting here. The order of execution of the code will be as follows:

```
const [vaults, setVaults] = useState({});
```

Initialize state variable vaults as `{}`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    ...
  }, []);
```

The callback inside `useEffect` is registered, but will not run immediately.

```
console.log('vaults outside useffect: ', vaults);
```

This will print `{}` now because of initial value.

If you `return` some JSX, it will be rendered now.

After that `useEffect` callback will be triggered.

```
async function loadBloackchainData() {
      ...
}
loadBloackchainData();
```

In `loadBloackchainData` function call it works as expected until the `// ALL GOOD TILL HERE` comment.

```
setVaults(vaults => ({
        ...vaults,
        [name]: {
           totalSupply,
           totalBorrowed,
           capUtilRate,
        },
      }));
console.log('vaults inside useffect: ', vaults); // {}
```

The `setVaults` call will not update the value `vaults` immediately, rather React batches such updates to state and will be run later. So `console.log` will print the current value of `{}` for `vaults`.
If you want `console.log` to have value with which state is updated, maybe run some logic with it, you can try:

```
setVaults(vaults => {
  const updatedState = ({
        ...vaults,
        [name]: {
           totalSupply,
           totalBorrowed,
           capUtilRate,
        },
  });
  console.log('vaults inside useffect: ', updatedState.vaults);
  return updatedState });
```

Answer (score 2):

`setVaults` has asynchronous logic. I said logic because it doesn't return any `Promise`. After calling `setVaults`, It does update state, but when console logging after that, you may not notice it.

Create another `useEffect` below it to check whether it's being changed.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Updated Vaults: ', vaults);
}, [vaults]);
```

Comment: just did it, still empty. Also console logs outside the first useEffect and even if I pass vaults to children still all empty.

Comment: You might want to take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56838392/how-to-call-an-async-function-inside-a-useeffect-in-react) too.

Comment: yep, that is exactly what I did

Comment: I tried to reproduce this [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-worker-7q8h1?file=/src/App.js). Could you confirm this is similar?

Answer (score 1):

Setting up state in React is an async process, which means it's not guaranteed that you will have the updated value available right after you update the state.

Above could be the reason of why you might not get the value in  `console.log('vaults inside useffect: ', vaults);`.

Another thing that might be causing the issue is the same name that you are using in two different place. i.e.

```js
const [vaults, setVaults] = useState({});

&

setVaults(vaults => ({
   ...vaults,
   [name]: {
      totalSupply,
      totalBorrowed,
      capUtilRate,
   },
}));
```

In above code, you are using the same name `vaults`, which can make a difference here.

Try changing the code to below and see if it works.

```js
setVaults(prevVaults => ({
   ...prevVaults,
   [name]: {
      totalSupply,
      totalBorrowed,
      capUtilRate,
   },
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

setVaults is an async operation, It won't update immediately, To watch the change use useEffect with the dependency of vaults.

```
const [vaults, setVaults] = useState({});
async function loadBloackchainData() {
  const web3 = new Web3("https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545/");
  const vault = new web3.eth.Contract(VaultABI, testnet.Vaults[0].address);
  const name = await vault.methods.symbol().call();
  console.log("name: ", name); // ok data is logged correctly
  const totalSupply = parseInt(await vault.methods.totalSupply().call());
  console.log("totalSupply: ", totalSupply); // ok data is logged correctly
  const totalBorrowed = parseInt(await vault.methods.vaultDebtVal().call());
  console.log("totalBorrowed: ", totalBorrowed); // ok data is logged correctly
  const capUtilRate = Number.isNaN(totalSupply / totalBorrowed)
    ? 0
    : totalSupply / totalBorrowed;
  console.log("capUtilRate: ", capUtilRate); // ok data is logged correctly

  // ALL GOOD TILL HERE

  setVaults((prev) => ({
    ...prev,
    [name]: {
      totalSupply,
      totalBorrowed,
      capUtilRate,
    },
  }));
  console.log("vaults inside useffect: ", vaults); // {}
}

useEffect(() => {
  loadBloackchainData();
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log("vaults outside useffect: ", vaults); // First render {}, after setVaults you will get object
}, [vaults]);
```