# React Native useEffect - Warning: An effect function must not return anything besides a function, which is used for clean-up

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

I would like to implement a single function to check if a specific seat out 20 seats available is booked or not. If it is, it returns red and if it's not, a green is returned.

I implemented the fetch function as

```
const getSeatColor = (seat, vid) => {
    const [color, setColor] = useState(0);

    useEffect(async () => {
      const response = await fetch(
        `http://192.168.8.100/dbops/actions/seat_status.php?seat=${seat}&vid=${vid}`
      );
      const result = await response.json();
      setColor(result.message);
    }, []);

    return color;
  };

  const vid = 4;
  const seat1Color = getSeatColor(1, vid);
  const seat2Color = getSeatColor(2, vid);
  const seat3Color = getSeatColor(3, vid);
  const seat4Color = getSeatColor(4, vid);

return (
    <Screen style={{ paddingBottom: 5 }}>
         {/* Seat 1 starts */}
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.seat} >
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="seat" size={40} color={seat1Color} />
            <Button title="1" style={{ width: 20 }} color={seat1Color} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          {/* Seat 1 ends */}
          {/* Seat 2 starts */}
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.seat} >
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="seat" size={40} color={seat2Color} />
            <Button title="2" style={{ width: 20 }} color={seat2Color} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          {/* Seat 2 ends */}
          <View style={styles.seat}></View>
          <View style={styles.seat}></View>
          {/* Seat 3 starts */}
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.seat} >
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="seat" size={40} color={seat3Color} />
            <Button title="3" style={{ width: 20 }} color={seat3Color} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
     </Screen>
)
```

The green or red comes out ok but I get this Warning: An effect function must not return anything besides a function, which is used for clean-up.

I tried this [How to call an async function inside a UseEffect() in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56838392/how-to-call-an-async-function-inside-a-useeffect-in-react/56838433#56838433) but the same warning pops up. Please help or could there be another way to achieve this?

Comment: You're returning a promise using the async keyword directly as the callback argument

Comment: Thank you @Carlos for the feedback and your time. Surely that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a promise using the async keyword directly as the callback argument.
Try re-writing your useEffect like this:

```js
    useEffect(() => {
    (async() => {
    const response = await fetch(
        `http://192.168.8.100/dbops/actions/seat_status.php?seat=${seat}&vid=${vid}`
      );
      const result = await response.json();
      setColor(result.message);
      })()
    }, []);
```

or wrap that code inside of another function and call it inside of  useEffect

```js
const fetchData = async () => {
const response = await fetch(
        `http://192.168.8.100/dbops/actions/seat_status.php?seat=${seat}&vid=${vid}`
      );
      const result = await response.json();
      setColor(result.message);
}
useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
}, []);
```

Comment: Thank you @Carlos. Your first code snippet helped and also needed a return statement `const getSeatColor = (seat, vid) => {
    const [color, setColor] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
      (async () => {
        const response = await fetch(
          `http://192.168.8.100/dbops/actions/seat_status.php?seat=${seat}&vid=${vid}`
        );
        const result = await response.json();
        setColor(result.message);
      })();
    }, []);

    return color;
  };` Thank you

Answer (score 0):

useEffect not accept async function.

You can try make this:

```js
const getSeatColor = (seat, vid) => {
    const [color, setColor] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
      (async => {
         const response = await fetch(`http://192.168.8.100/dbops/actions/seat_status.php?seat=${seat}&vid=${vid}`);
         const result = await response.json();
         setColor(result.message);
      })();
    }, []);

    return color;
};
```

Comment: Thank you @Dijalma Silva for the feedback and your time. Your code snippet helped, however async is to be taken out of () like.   
    `.....
    useEffect(() => {
      (async () => {
        const response = await fetch(
          `http://192.168.8.100/dbops/actions/seat_status.php?seat=${seat}&vid=${vid}`
        );
        const result = await response.json();
        setColor(result.message);
      })();
    }, []);

    return color;
  };  `