# how make a useEffect async

Tags: reactjs

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (names.length !== 0) {
      createName(id);
    }
    getName(id);
  }, [names]);
```

Here both the function createName and getName is a api call that returns a promise.

Now Sometime, createName delays which is causing getName to execute without a data.

So, how to make this usEffect async using async await ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call an async function inside a UseEffect() in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56838392/how-to-call-an-async-function-inside-a-useeffect-in-react)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create an async function in `useEffect` and call it after:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const asyncFn = async () => {
    if (names.length !== 0) {
      await createName(id);
    }
    getName(id);
  };

  asyncFn();
}, [names]);
```