# Using async/promise with useeffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, asynchronous, promise

I have json file which i load and i use Hook to SetState to it.
After SetState i want to use state with Value of Json to my function. But my function is executing with null value because setState doesnt load before Execute function.
Here is code

```
 const fetchQuestions = async () => {
        const data = await require("../../question.json");
        await setQuestions(
            data.map((item: IQuestion) => ({
                    id: item.id,
                    question: item.question,
                    answers: item.answers
                })
            ))
        await setQuestionsArray(
            data.map((item: IQuestion) => ({
                    id: item.id,
                    name: item.question
                })
            ))
        return questionsArray
    }
```

There is Function which i pass questionArray :

```
 const handleQuest = (array: Array<IArrayQuestion>) => {
        if (array.length > 0) {
            const numberArray = array.length
            const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (numberArray - 0))
            const p = (array[random])
            setQuestion(p.name)
            setShuffleRandom(!shuffleRandom)
        }
    }
```

And  i use it in useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (nick.length < 1) {
            navigate('/quiz')
        }
        fetchQuestions().then((res)=>{
            if (questionsArray.length > 0){
                handleQuest(res)
            }
            else{console.log("Nothing")}
        })
    }, [])
```

It still doesnt work. I dont have value in my function after promise

Comment: You can't `await` a setState call, and you can't use the updated state value in the same render cycle.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Comment: also: [How to call an async function inside a UseEffect() in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56838392/how-to-call-an-async-function-inside-a-useeffect-in-react)

Comment: You can save the array that you pass to `setQuestionsArray` to a variable and return that variable from `fetchQuestions`, then, you can use `res` instead of `questionsArray` when the `fetchQuestions` promise is fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

Separate data fetching logic from your application components. First write `fetchQuestions` -

```js
async function fetchQuestions() {
  const data = await require("../../questions.json")
  return data.map(item => ({
    id: item.id,
    question: item.question,
    answers: item.answers
  })
}
```

Your component shouldn't copy data to multiple states. There should be a [single source of truth](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lessons-learned). You don't need multiple question arrays or a copy of the current question. Instead use derived (computed) state to reference the "current" question -

```js
import { fetchQuestions } from "./api"

function MyComponent() {
  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([])
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0)
  
  useEffect(async _ => {
    try {
      const q = await fetchQuestions()
      setQuestions(q)
      setCurrent(Math.floor(Math.random() * q.length)))
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message)
    }
  ), [])

  return <div>
    <Question question={questions[current]} />
  </div>
}
```

Your `Question` component would look something like this -

```js
function Question({ question }) {
  return <div data-question-id={question.id}>
    Q: {question.name}
    {question.answers.map((answer, key) =>
      <Answer key={key} answer={answer} />
    )}
  </div>
}
```

Write the `Answer` component, and so on ...

Answer (score -1):

You need to add questionsArray in useEffect dependencies, but because it's a state, you should do it in two useEffects:

first fetch data:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (nick.length < 1) {
        navigate('/quiz')
    }
    fetchQuestions()
}, [])
```

And in second useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (questionsArray.length > 0){
        handleQuest(questionsArray)
    }
    else{console.log("Nothing")}
}, [questionsArray])
```

when questionsArray is in useEffect dependencies, with every fetch, it will refresh and new questions will be added.