# Access an array from promise value and make it available to be used globally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I am receiving an array from a promise function:

```
function func() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //...
        return someData;
    })
}
```

then I can see the promise value using async/await:

```
async function getArrayContent() {
    const a = await func();
    console.log(a);
}
```

this does display the correct content however, I am looking to access the array and its contents in so it can be used outside the async `getArrayContent()` function. please note that I can't change `func()` as the promise is necessary to return data I am retrieving. Also, `return a` does not work because whenever I am logging the `getArrayContent()` which returns `a` it just shows another pending promise. However, in this promise it does show that the state is fulfilled and it does have the necessary value but I still cannot access that value outside the functions. I tried adding a variable outside `getArrayContent()` but variable remains undefined.
I am using this in Reactjs and some of the solutions I tried both did not work and/or caused an infinite loop.
Other posts on stackoverflow did not help either because they only shows how to log value inside a promise with `.then()` which I cannot use.

I need to be able to display the area in React with the map function

Comment: Once in async land, always in async land. Though as regards React you can `setState` with `a` inside the async function and it will update state as expected and be available the next render cycle.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: also see: [How to call an async function inside a UseEffect() in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56838392/how-to-call-an-async-function-inside-a-useeffect-in-react)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do precisely what you are asking here.

As @pilchard succinctly said:

> Once in async land, always in async land.

However, one thing you could do is, `await` the function and pass it as a prop to a child component (and only show the child component when the data is ready), Now you can use the value synchronously in the child component.