# How do I format result of promise.all

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have result from DB with object below. I can only print it to console. How do I eg. use it in formatted console output such as

```
console.log(`Hello ${name} (${age}) from ${city}`);
```

Do I save it into array locally and the use it in react component? What is the best practice?

Output from code below:

```
{ name: 'alice', city: 'New York', age: 34 }
```

Promise:

```
 Promise.all(promises).then(([res1, res2]) => {
    getProfile(res1, res2).then(console.log);
  })
```

Comment: So your question is how to print that object as a "Hello..." message? Then your question doesn't relate to `Promise.all`, really.

Comment: ``getProfile(res1, res2).then(({ name, city, age }) => console.log(`Hello ${name} (${age}) from ${city}`))``

Comment: Are you fetching within a component? Possibly look at [How to call an async function inside a UseEffect() in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56838392/how-to-call-an-async-function-inside-a-useeffect-in-react)

Comment: @pilchard yes that is pattern Im looking for. thank you