# Remix.js with react.js application with "TypeError: (0 , import_voteCounter.updateVotes) is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an imported async function from another file that only returns the string literal "test string" and does not do anything else. Here is the code for that:

```
  export const testString = async () => {
        return 'This is a test string'
  }
```

In my main react.js file I have the following code:

```
  import { testString } from '~/utils/voteCounter.server';
  
  const [testData, setTestData] = useState('');


  useEffect(() => { 

      const fetchData = async () => {
          return await testString();
      }

      fetchData().then(res =>  setTestData(res)).catch(console.error)

  }, [])
```

I tried solutions for this on:

[How to call an async function inside a UseEffect() in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56838392/how-to-call-an-async-function-inside-a-useeffect-in-react)

But I still get the following error:

"TypeError: (0 , import_voteCounter.testString) is not a function"

What should I change with my code?

Comment: good news is I tried your code and it works on my machine. Bad news is, I have no idea why it doesn't work for you

Comment: maybe it's something with the import? what happens when you do `console.log(testString)`, maybe it needs a full path

Comment: Yea thanks for the suggestion. It was the import statement and me adding "server" to the import statement. This is what works for me:   


  `import { testString } from '~/utils/voteCounter.'; `

Comment: excellent you can post it as an answer if you want