Next.js App Router - Why does useEffect in a Client Component cause a hydration mismatch in nested layouts?
I'm encountering a hydration mismatch error when using the Next.js 13 App Router. I have a nested layout where a client component fetches data using useEffect. When I navigate to the page, I get a warning about the text content not matching between server-side rendering (SSR) and client-side hydration.
Here’s a simplified code structure:
Layout: app/layout.tsx
export const metadata = {
  title: 'My App',
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <nav>My Navbar</nav>
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

Page: app/dashboard/page.tsx
'use client';

import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function DashboardPage() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const response = await fetch('/api/data');
      const result = await response.json();
      setData(result);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Dashboard</h1>
      {data ? <p>{data.message}</p> : <p>Loading...</p>}
    </div>
  );
}

When I navigate to /dashboard, I get the following warning in the console:

Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "Loading..." Client: "Hello from API"

Question:

Why am I seeing this hydration error?
Is this due to using useEffect for client-side data fetching in a component within a nested layout?
How can I resolve this and prevent mismatches between server-side and client-side rendering?


This answer may help you and provide additional information on nicer ways to handle async functions and utilzing await to ensure the useEffect doesn't close before state is updated: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56838577/7733570
