# Doing an asynchronous operation inside a functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I usually take care of any promises or asynchronous operations in the `componentDidMount` or `componentWillMount` lifecycle methods, but now I am using only functional components.

So I have something like this:

```
export async function MyComponent () {
  const data = await myPromiseFunction()

  return (
    <>
      DO SOMETHING!
    </>
  )
}
```

This obviously cannot be done because we are returning a promise when using `MyComponent`. So my question becomes how can I do asynchronous operations within the functional component?

Do I just have to accept that they have to be done elsewhere and receive my necessary data as props? Or is there a cleaner way to get around this?

Comment: https://tinkerylabs.com/ajax-calls-with-react-hooks/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need Hooks; namely Effects hook.

there you can send http request within `useEffect(() =>{ callMyApi()})` block.

you can see an example here:
[React Hook Warnings for async function in useEffect: useEffect function must return a cleanup function or nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332321/react-hook-warnings-for-async-function-in-useeffect-useeffect-function-must-ret)