# Calling an async function inside the if condition of useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I call a redux action inside the if block of `useEffect` hook:

```
useEffect(async () => {
    if (nameId && selectedGroup === 'AGM') {
        const subPeople = await getSubPeople(nameId);
    }
}, [nameId, selectedGroup]);
```

I have two select boxes. If the person types in the `name` select box, I store the selected id of `name` in the `nameId` state. If user selects a group, I store it in `selectedGroup`, so only if both conditions match I need to call an API endpoint to get the `subPeople`.

If I comment this code there is no error. How can I make the snippet work?

Comment: someone wrote a `useAsyncEffect` thing just for this ... also there's [this question on SO that may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332321/react-hook-warnings-for-async-function-in-useeffect-useeffect-function-must-ret)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can move the async logic into a separate function and call it inside `useEffect`, since `useEffect`'s callback can't be async itself:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const getPeople = async () => {
    if (nameId && selectedGroup === 'AGM') {
      const subPeople = await getSubPeople(nameId);
      return subPeople; // Or set the state, etc.
    }
  }
  getPeople(); 
}, [nameId, selectedGroup]);
```