# JAVASCRIPT: Nothing was returned from render even though return statement exists

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have this `Display()` function which fetches events from the Google Calendar via an API and store each event's name via `element.summary` into the `events` set. And then once the `events` set is populated, I iterate through the set via `for (let item of events)` and create a new `<a>` tag for each event/item in the set using the name as the text via `<a>{item}</a>` (for e.g. `<a>call<a>`, then I push each `<a>` tag into a new array called `tabs` and then finally return the `tabs` array. The `events` set contains three items and when I `console.log`, I see the correct items ("call", "kist", & "go") in the set. However, once I `console.log` the `tabs` array, it only contains one `<a>` tag whose value is null whereas it is supposed to contain three `<a>` tags since it iterates through the `events` set which has three items and is supposed to create an `<a>` tag for each. Also, I get the error that `item is not defined` for the line `for (let item of events)`, somehow I cannot iterate through the `events` set. See [console output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWAf9.png).

```
function Display() {
    let events = new Set()
    let tabs = []
    ApiCalendar.listUpcomingEvents(10)
        .then(({result}: any) => {
            result.items.forEach(element => {
                    console.log(element.summary)
                    events.add(element.summary)
                }
            );
            console.log(events)
            for (let item of events)
                console.log(item)
                tabs.push(<a>{item}</a>)
            console.log(tabs)
            return tabs
        });
}
```

This is the class that I made in the same file as the above function, which basically renders a 'Log In' button if user is not logged in to their calendar, or renders the array of `<a>` tags returned by the `Display()` function if user is already logged in. However, even though the `Display()` function above does return something (i.e. an array of `<a>` tags) and the `render()` function inside the class also returns a `<div>` element with the corresponding component inside the `div`, I get the error `Uncaught Error: Display(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.` I am new to JavaScript and have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated and thank you in advance.

```
export default class LoginControl extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            sign: ApiCalendar.sign,
        };
    }

    render() {
        const isLoggedIn = this.state.sign;
        let ele;

        if (isLoggedIn) {
            ele = <Display/>;
        } else {
            ele = <Button>'Sign In'</Button>;
        }

        return (
            <div>
                {ele}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: The `return` statement is not inside the `Display` functio but the callback in given to `then`

Comment: Always use curly braces on multi-line constructs, like your for-of here, since it's easy to add a line, like your `console.log(item)`, and break the logic since now, the actual body of the construct is outside its scope, like `tabs.push(<a>{item}</a>)` in your snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Display` function calls an async method and returns nothing. You will need to utilize state and effect inside `Display` to render returned data. But then, you will encounter errors if user navigates away from page before data is fetched.

Best solution for this problem would be to utilize `redux` and `redux-thunk`

---

#### Caution, untested code below

If you feel like you don't need redux, try this approach

```
async function fetchItems() {
  const result = await ApiCalendar.listUpcomingEvents(10);
  return result.result.items.map(({summary}) => summary);
}

function Display() {
  const [items, saveItems] = useState([]);
  const isMounted = useRef(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      isMounted.current = false;
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const items = await fetchItems();
      //Do not update state if component is unmounted
      if (isMounted.current) {
        saveItems(items);
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  return <>{items.map(item => <a key={item}>{item}</a>)}</>
}
```

If you want to render more than summary, you can do it like this

```
async function fetchItems() {
  const result = await ApiCalendar.listUpcomingEvents(10);
  return result.result.items.map(({summary, somethingElse}) => ({summary, somethingElse}));
  //can be replaced with return [...result.result.items]; to get all props
}

function Display() {

  //... Main logic of Display component is the same, 
  //so I wouldn't duplicate it here

  return <>{items.map(item => <div key={item.summary}>{item.summary} {item.somethingElse}</div>)}</>
}
```

Comment: I get the error: ```Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at fetchItem```

Comment: @HeartKiller well, "untested" means exactly that - it can throw errors. This specific one means `result` does not have `items`. Looking at code again, I think it should be `result.result.items.map`

Comment: It seems to work now but when i click button on the page to go to next page, I get this error: ```func.apply``` is not a function along with this warning:  It looks like you wrote useEffect(async () => ...) or returned a Promise. Instead, write the async function inside your effect and call it immediately:
```useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchData() {
    // You can await here
    const response = await MyAPI.getData(someId);
    // ...
  }
  fetchData();
}, [someId]); // Or [] if effect doesn't need props/state```

Comment: @HeartKiller see updated answer, that should solve it

Comment: thank you so much, it finally works perfect. Just a quick question, if I wanted more than one item (i.e, more than just the summary of an event from ```ApiCalendar.listUpcomingEvents()```, such as startTime and endTime of event), how would I adjust the code so that I can retrieve that information as well? I'm assuming I'll have to change something around ```return result.result.items.map(({summary}) => summary);
}```?

Comment: thank you so much for your patience and knowledge. I tried to upvote your solution but I couldn't since I didn't have enough reputation but I really appreciate your help and I have accepted your solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not returning anything on `Display` component.

You can't return a promise on a component so you need to make it inside `useEffect` using `react hooks` or `component lifecycle` - and no, you don't need redux just to achieve this.

```
function Display() {
    let events = new Set()
    let tabs = [];
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

    const getList = async () => {
      const res = await  ApiCalendar.listUpcomingEvents(10);

       setItems(res.items);
    }

    useEffect(async () => {
      getList();
    }, []);

  return items.map(item => <div>{item}</div>);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but: 1) Your code will fetch data on every render 2) React will show warning about memory leak if component is unmounted in process

Comment: oops I forgot to add the second argument `[]` empty array. it should only call the API once the component did mounted and not on every render

Comment: @IamL I get error ```setItems``` is not defined. Also I was wondering, is it supposed to be ```<div>{item.summary}</div>``` since I want the name of the event and not the entire object? Thanks.

Comment: @IamL I also get error ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null```.

Comment: @HeartKiller I updated the answer - I never tested it and just wrote from scratch

Comment: React will show a warning regardless because [you should **not** be returning a promise in the `useEffect` callback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53332321/1218980).