# How can I make sure that function 1 ends before function 2 starts within useeffect hook?

Tags: reactjs, api, async-await, dialogflow-es, use-effect

I created a chatbot and want to initiate two Dialogflow API calls within a useEffect Hook. Function 1 and function 2 are both async api calls. The wanted result is that it first finishes function 1 and then starts with function 2, but currently function 2 returns the value faster than function 1.

Do you have any idea how I can tell function 2 to wait until function 1 returns a value?

```
useEffect(
    () => {
      createChatSessionId();
      fetchEventAnswerFromDialogflow("Startevent" + chatId, chatId); // function 1
      fetchEventAnswerFromDialogflow("Frageevent1", chatId); // function 2
    }, // eslint-disable-next-line
    []
  );
```

Comment: Can we use a callback in `fetchEventAnswerFromDialogflow` else you need to use `async -await` (its already there in one of the answers below)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

API Calls are asynchronous.
When the compiler hits an async statement, it doesnt wait for it to finish, instead calls next statement.

Option one, (Using .then block) :-

```
  useEffect(
    () => {
      createChatSessionId();
      fetchEventAnswerFromDialogflow("Startevent" + chatId, chatId).then(rep=>{
      fetchEventAnswerFromDialogflow("Frageevent1", chatId);})
        .catch(err){
          console.log(err)
         }
    }, // eslint-disable-next-line
    []
  );
```

Option two - As per ES6 using async await. I'd suggest not to make useEffect callback as async, instead make a new async function inside useEffect and call that.

```
useEffect(
    () => {
      createChatSessionId();
      const getData = async() =>{
         await fetchEventAnswerFromDialogflow("Startevent" + chatId, chatId);
         await fetchEventAnswerFromDialogflow("Frageevent1", chatId);  //Can remove await 
             //here, depending upon usecase
      }
      getData();
    }, // eslint-disable-next-line
    []
  );
```

Comment: If fetchEventAnswerFromDialogflow does not return a promise, making useEffect async and awaiting for the function wont do anything. Beside making useEffect async is not a proper thing to do [Here is why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332321/react-hook-warnings-for-async-function-in-useeffect-useeffect-function-must-ret)

Comment: Please check the stack forum. Link provided in previous comment

Comment: thnx for the link

Comment: well, we learned sth new today! didnt know that about the async in `useEffect` so I need to change some forgotten parts of my code. I'll delete my answer since yours is correct. thnx again :)