# React Hooks - Set State variable from Promise in another function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, es6-promise

I'm trying not to write all my code in the same file, and to extract commonly used functions like downloading an image from Firebase to separate functions/files.

I have two functions in React named

1. `OfferCard` (renders a card based on props)
2. `getImage`  (fetches an image's download-URL from Firebase Storage, to provide an image to the OfferCard component).

I'm trying to fetch an image file from `getImage` and display that image in the returned `<CardMedia />` image property from the `OfferCard` functional component.

The problem I'm facing is, getImage **doesn't fetch the data and return it in time** for the `setOfferImage`. Meaning the state variable `offerImage` remains `null` or `undefined`.

In the console, I can see that the `getImage` is console logging the value **AFTER** the `OfferCard` console logs the value/.

I believe it's an issue with asynchronous code and promises but am not too sure how to resolve this one.

**OfferCard.js:**

```
import getImage from '../utils/helperFunctions/getImage';

export default function OfferCard(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [offerImage, setOfferImage] = React.useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (props.image) {
            initFirebase();
            setOfferImage(getImage(props.image));
            console.log(offerImage)
        }
    }, [])

    return (

        <Link href={`/offers/${props.id}`}>
            <Card className={classes.card} >
                {offerImage ? 
                    <CardMedia
                    image={offerImage}
                /> : <CircularProgress/>
                }
           </Card>
        </Link>
    )
}
```

**getImage:**

```
export default function getImage(path) {
    let storage = firebase.storage();
    let pathReference = storage.ref(`${path}.png`);

    pathReference.getDownloadURL()
        .then((url) => {
            console.log("returning", url);
            return (url);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            // Handle any errors
            console.log("Could not get image: ", error);
        });
}
```

Comment: So is it an issue that the `console.log(offerImage)` is simply logging the *current state* and not the *next state* enqueued from `setOfferImage(getImage(props.image));` a line above, or is it something else entirely?

Comment: @DrewReese I think you're right that maybe the `console.log` statements were logging old values, I hadn't thought of that. But the issue I was facing was that the conditional ternary operator in the `offerImage? ` section was only ever returning `false`, since offerImage was being returned null by the `getImage` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem in this is that your `getImage` function is actually a void function, as it will reach the end of the code without finding any return, as the `return(url)` is performed on a second moment.
The solution is to make that function asynchronous, returning a Promise:

```
export default async function getImage(path) {
  let storage = firebase.storage();
  let pathReference = storage.ref(`${path}.png`);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    pathReference.getDownloadURL()
      .then((url) => {
        console.log("returning", url);
        resolve(url);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Handle any errors
        reject(error)
        console.log("Could not get image: ", error);
      });
  })
}
```

So that you can then await it in your useEffect. Be aware you can't actually await inside an useEffect ([learn more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332321/react-hook-warnings-for-async-function-in-useeffect-useeffect-function-must-ret)), so your OfferCard.js will become

```
useEffect(() => {
  const getImageAsync = async () => {
    const url = await getImage(props.image)
    if (url)
      setOfferImage(url)
    else {
      // handle error
    }
  }

  if (props.image) {
    initFirebase();
    getImageAsync();
  }
}, [])
```

Comment: Thanks Nicola for the quick and correct reply! One small tweak to the code you recommended was to make the `getImage` function async by `export default async function getImage(path)`. Thanks for the help so quickly.

Answer (score 1):

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchImg = async () => {
    const res = await getImage(props.image)
    setOfferImage(res);
    // `setOfferImage` is async 
    // `console.log(offerImage)` there will be console previous value of `offerImage`
  }
  if (props.image) {
    initFirebase();
    fetchImg()
  }
}, [props.image])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const [imgUrl, setImageUrl] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
    console.log('XXXXXXXXXX useEffect');
    if (isSummit) {
        uploadToFireBase();
    }
}, [imgUrl])
```

.

```
function start() { uploadFile(file) }
```

.

```
async function uploadFile(file) {

    // Create the file metadata
    /** @type {any} */
    const metadata = {
        contentType: 'image/jpeg'
    };

    // Upload file and metadata to the object 'images/mountains.jpg'
    const storageRef = ref(storage, `image/${v4() + file.name}`);
    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file, metadata);

    // Listen for state changes, errors, and completion of the upload.
    uploadTask.on('state_changed',
        (snapshot) => {
            // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
            const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
            console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
            switch (snapshot.state) {
                case 'paused':
                    console.log('Upload is paused');
                    break;
                case 'running':
                    console.log('Upload is running');
                    break;
            }
        },
        (error) => {
            // A full list of error codes is available at
            // https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/handle-errors
            switch (error.code) {
                case 'storage/unauthorized':
                    // User doesn't have permission to access the object
                    break;
                case 'storage/canceled':
                    // User canceled the upload
                    break;

                // ...

                case 'storage/unknown':
                    // Unknown error occurred, inspect error.serverResponse
                    break;
            }
        },
        async () => {
            // Upload completed successfully, now we can get the download URL
            getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then(async (downloadURL) => {
                await setImageUrl(downloadURL);



            });


        }
    );
}
```

this work for me .

i use async and await to setHook ( await setImageUrl(downloadURL); )

And useEffect to track if my variable imgUrl is changed .