# React mapping through a query result is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, react-hooks

I'm using React and I'm trying to map the result of a GET request to the db to display some tabs in my page.

This is my GET request:

```
useEffect(async ()=>{
  const a = await getCategories();
  setCategories(a)
    
},[])
  
const [categories, setCategories] = useState()
```

I then store the returned array in my functional component state with useEffect hook:

```
useEffect(async ()=>{
  const a = await getCategories();
  setCategories(a)

},[])
  
const [categories, setCategories] = useState()
```

At the end, in the render I try to map through the state array like this:

```
<Nav variant="tabs" >
  {categories.map((category, index) => (
    <Nav.Item key={index}>
      <Nav.Link
      eventKey={`link-${index}`}
      onClick={() => setCategory(category.category)}
      >
        {category}
      </Nav.Link>
    </Nav.Item>
  ))}
</Nav>
```

I'm getting a **TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined**

I think that's because it runs the map before i have the array stored in the state but i have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: Could you include the code for ```getCategories()```?

Comment: @yuRa that code is working well, i tested it with postman and was returning an array as i expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the default value for categories using an empty array:

```
const [categories, setCategories] = useState([])
```

You can also optionally add a defensive conditional mapping by checking if categories is iterable:

```
{Array.isArray(categories) && categories.map((category, index) => (..)}
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: How does it not answer the question :D ?

Comment: Thank you very much! So by having the empty array it maps over the empty one and when i assign the array fetched from the db it maps again over the new one, right?

Answer (score 2):

`async` in `useEffect` will cause a warning, so use it like: [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332321/react-hook-warnings-for-async-function-in-useeffect-useeffect-function-must-ret)

```
useEffect(()=>{

const fetchData = async () => {
      const a = await getCategories();
      setCategories(a);
    };
 
    fetchData();

},[])
```

and declare a default empty array in state:

```
const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
```

Or you can validate that categories are available to iterate like this:

```
<Nav variant="tabs" >
  {categories.length > 0 && categories.map((category, index) => (
    <Nav.Item key={index}>
      <Nav.Link
      eventKey={`link-${index}`}
      onClick={() => setCategory(category.category)}
      >
        {category}
      </Nav.Link>
    </Nav.Item>
  ))}
</Nav>
```

Comment: Great, it works now, thank you!

Why the async await on the useEffect could lead to problems but an async await inside of an useEffect doesn't? Kinda confusing to me.

Comment: You can read here. https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right, before rendering, the categories is empty. You have to check whether categories is empty or not before rendering:

```
return !categories.length ?   
 <Nav variant="tabs" >
   {categories.map((category, index) => (
     <Nav.Item key={index}>
       <Nav.Link
         eventKey={`link-${index}`}
         onClick={() => 
 setCategory(category.category)}
      >
        {category}
      </Nav.Link>
    </Nav.Item>
  ))}
</Nav>

:
<h1>Loading...</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer without looking at `setCategories()`

You can solve this with checking if the array exists before you map it

```
array & array.map(item => {
    return item * 2
})
```

This won't return undefined because the first condition will fail.

Comment: The setCategories is part of the useState hook.
It works as a this.setState for class based components.