# Memory Leak on React App that uses RealTime Firebase DataBase

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, memory-leaks, axios

I´m not sure how to use useEffect(), I keep getting

> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is
> a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix,
> cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup
> function.
> *in Login*

here is my component:

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import fire from '../fire';

import Sign from './sign';
import Dashboard from './dashboard';
import Map from './journey/map';

const Login = () => {


const [user, setUser ] = useState('');
const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
const [emailError, setEmailError] = useState('');
const [passwordError, setPasswordError] = useState('');
const [hasAccount, setHasAccount] = useState(false);


const clearInputs = () => {
    setEmail('');
    setPassword('');
}

const clearErrors = () => {
    setEmailError('');
    setPasswordError('');
}

const handleLogin = () => {
    clearErrors();
    fire
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .catch(err => {
            switch(err.code){
                case 'auth/invalid-email':
                case 'auth/user-disabled':
                case 'auth/user-not-found':
                    setEmailError(err.message);
                    break;
                case 'auth/wrong-password':
                    setPasswordError(err.message);
                    break;
            }
        });
}

const handleSignUp = () => {
    clearErrors();
    fire
    .auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .catch(err => {
        switch(err.code){
            case 'auth/email-already-in-use':
            case 'auth/invalid-email':
                setEmailError(err.message);
                break;
            case 'auth/weak-password':
                setPasswordError(err.message);
                break;
        }
    });
    return 
}

const handleLogOut = () => {
    fire.auth().signOut();
};


const authListener = (user_id) => {
    user_id = '';
    fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if(user) {
            clearInputs();
            setUser(user);
            user_id = user.email;
        } else {
            setUser('');
        }
    });
}

useEffect(() => {
    authListener();
    
}, []);

    return (
        
        <div>
            
            {user ? (
                <div>
                <Dashboard 
                handleLogOut={handleLogOut}
                user_id={user.email}
                />
                <Map 
                user_id={user.email}
                />
                </div>
            ) : (
                <Sign 
                email={email}
                setEmail={setEmail}
                password={password}
                setPassword={setPassword}
                handleLogin={handleLogin}
                handleSignUp={handleSignUp}
                hasAccount={hasAccount}
                setHasAccount={setHasAccount}
                emailError={emailError}
                passwordError={passwordError}
                />  
                
            )}
            
            
        

        </div>
    );

}

export default Login;
```

I am using firebase authentication.

**Notes** the memory leak happens only when I enter into the child component and then go back and log out of the app.
here is the child component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faCaretSquareLeft } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

import MapItem from '../mapItems';
import Card from './card';

class Cards extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        journey_name: [],
        cards: [],
        data: [],
        hero: [],
        loading: true
    }

    this.cards = this.cards.bind(this);        
}


fetchCards = () => {

    axios.get('myapi').then(response => {
        console.log('fetchCards',response);
        this.setState({
            journey_name: response.data.journey_name,
            cards: response.data.cards,
        })
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(`fetchCards error : ${error}`);
    }) 

}

fetchData = () => {
    axios.get('my api').then(response => {
        console.log('fetchdata',response);
        this.setState({
            data: response.data,
            hero: response.data.hero
        })
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(`fetchData error : ${error}`);
    })
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchCards();
    this.fetchData();

}

cards = () => {
    return (
        this.state.cards.map(card => {
            return (
                <Card
                    key={card.card_id}
                    card_name={card.card_name}
                    explanation={card.explanation}
                    image_url={card.image}
                    points={card.points}
                    reference={card.reference}
                />
            )
        })
    )
}


render() {

    return (
        <div className='cards-page'>
            <div className='cards-page__navbar'>
                <Link to='/'>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCaretSquareLeft} />
                </Link>
                <MapItem
                    name={this.state.data.name}
                    level={this.state.hero.level}
                    points={this.state.hero.points}
                    class='cards-user'
                />
            </div>

            <div className='cards-rail'>
                {this.cards()}
            </div>

            <div className='footer'> by Johnattan M Angeles </div>
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default Cards;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Hook Warnings for async function in useEffect: useEffect function must return a cleanup function or nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332321/react-hook-warnings-for-async-function-in-useeffect-useeffect-function-must-ret)

Answer (score 0):

Though you should probably unsubscribe from the firebase onAuthStateChanged event, I think your issue may be with the axios fetch requests. If they later resolve *after* you've already navigated away from the child component then they are updating state of an unmounted component. You should [cancel](https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation) any pending requests when the component unmounts.

```
class Cards extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    ...

    // Create cancel token & source
    const CancelToken = axio.CancelToken;
    this.source = CancelToken.source();
  }


  fetchCards = () => {
    axios.get(
      'myapi',
      { cancelToken: this.source.token }, // <-- pass cancel token W/ request
    ).then(response => {
      console.log('fetchCards',response);
      this.setState({
        journey_name: response.data.journey_name,
        cards: response.data.cards,
      })
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(`fetchCards error : ${error}`);
    }) 

  }

  fetchData = () => {
    axios.get(
      'my api',
      { cancelToken: source.token }, // <-- pass cancel token W/ request
    ).then(response => {
      console.log('fetchdata',response);
      this.setState({
        data: response.data,
        hero: response.data.hero
      })
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(`fetchData error : ${error}`);
    })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchCards();
    this.fetchData();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.source.cancel('Operation cancelled by user'); // <-- cancel on unmount
  }

  ...
}
```