# useEffect on infinite loop using async fetch function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to understand why the following useEffect is running in an infinite loop. I made the `fetchSchedule` helper function to call the `getSchedule` service (using Axios to query the API endpoint). Reason I did not define this function inside the useEffect hook is because I would like to alternatively also call it whenever the `onStatus` function is invoked (which toggles a Boolean PUT request on a separate endpoint).

The eslinter is requiring `fetchSchedule` be added to the array of dependencies, which seems to be triggering the infinite loop.

The way it should work is fetching the data from the database on first render, and then only each time either the `value` prop is updated or the `onStatus` button is toggled.

So far my research seems to point that this may have something to do with the way useEffect behaves with async functions and closures.  I’m still trying to understand Hooks and evidently there’s something I’m not getting in my code…

```
import React, { useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import useStateRef from 'react-usestateref';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { getSchedule, updateStatus } from '../../services/scheduleService';
import Status from './status';
// import Pagination from './pagination';

const List = ({ value }) => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  const [schedule, setSchedule, ref] = useStateRef([]);
  // const [schedule, setSchedule] = useState([]);

  const fetchSchedule = useCallback(async () => {
    const { data } = await getSchedule(value);
    setSchedule(data);
  }, [value, setSchedule]);

  const onStatus = (id) => {
    updateStatus(id);
    fetchSchedule();
    console.log('fetch', ref.current[0].completed);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchSchedule();
  }, [fetchSchedule]);
return (...)
```

Comment: maybe this answer can help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332321/react-hook-warnings-for-async-function-in-useeffect-useeffect-function-must-ret

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update March 2021**

After working with the repo owner for `react-usestateref`, the package now functions as originally intended and is safe to use as a replacement for `useState` as of version `1.0.5`. The current implementation looks like this:

```
function useStateRef(defaultValue) {
  var [state, setState] = React.useState(defaultValue);
  var ref = React.useRef(state);

  var dispatch = React.useCallback(function(val) {
    ref.current = typeof val === "function" ?
    val(ref.current) : val;

    setState(ref.current);
  }, []);

  return [state, dispatch, ref];
};
```

---

You would be fine if it weren't for this `react-usestateref` import.

The hook returns a plain anonymous function for setting state which means that it will be recreated on every render - you cannot usefully include it in any dependency array as that too will be updated on every render. However, since the function is being returned from an unknown custom hook (and regardless, ESLint would correctly identify that it is not a proper setter function) you'll get warnings when you don't.

The 'problem' which it tries to solve is also going to introduce bad practice into your code - it's a pretty way to avoid properly handling dependencies which are there to make your code safer.

If you go back to a standard state hook I believe this code will work fine. Instead of trying to get a ref of the state in `onStatus`, make it async as well and return the data from fetchSchedule as well as setting it.

```
const [schedule, setSchedule] = useState([]);

const fetchSchedule = useCallback(async () => {
  const { data } = await getSchedule(value);
  setSchedule(data);
  return data;
}, [value]);

const onStatus = async (id) => {
  updateStatus(id);
  const data = await fetchSchedule();
};

useEffect(() => {
  fetchSchedule();
}, [fetchSchedule]);
```

Alternatively, although again I wouldn't really recommend using this, we could actually write a safe version of the useStateRef hook instead:

```
function useStateRef(defaultValue) {
    var [state, setState] = React.useState(defaultValue);

    var ref = React.useRef(defaultValue);
    ref.current = state; 

    return [state, setState, ref];
}
```

A state setter function is always referentially identical throughout the lifespan of a component so this can be included in a dependency array without causing the effect/callback to be recreated.

Comment: I'm not sure why the `useEffect()` is in your `useStateRef()` hook, wouldn't it be more correct to just do `var ref = useRef(); ref.current = state;` synchronously? Otherwise the ref would actually refer to the previous state until after the render phase is completed.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I had it as that originally but I changed it as I was under the impression nothing dependent on `state` could read its new value until after the render was complete. Therefore tying the `ref` to `state` with an effect would more closely resemble how state actually works. Happy to change it back if this is not good reasoning. Edit: although I guess the whole point of this is not to work how state actually works...

Comment: I did put it back as I do see how that more closely fits the original purpose of the hook.