# What is the best way to store a array objects in React 17.0.1

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a project setup in node, express as backend and react as frontend, In node i have written

```
JSON.stringify(`${some_value}`);
```

and it is saved in the database.

To fetch, I am using useEffect hook and axios.get to the records from the database and rendered in the jsx

Is the above method the an good practice ???

```
const [allProjects, setAllProjects] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    ... Axios.get ... other code
    setAllProjects(result); // if successfull response store it in state
```

In the return I have the below code

```
return (
    ... other code
    {allProjects.map((value) => {
        ... other codes
        allProjects.responsibilites.map((value) => {
            return(
                <p>{value.role}</p>
            )
        })}
```

allProjects.responsibilities has

```
[{"role":"manager","name":"Test"},{"role":"manager","name":"Test 2"}]
```

I am getting **TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined**

Comment: is `allProjects.map` an array or `allProjects.responsibilites.map`? you are  mapping with of them

Comment: Initially before you are rendering your value is null so map is coming as undefined. You can add condition like when allProjects has data then map.

Comment: you should check initial `useState` it should initialize to empty array like `const [.....] = useState([])`

Comment: allProjects is array of objects ---  {{id: 12345, name:"project name", responsibilities: "[{"role":"manager","name":"Test"}, {"role":"manager","name":"Test 12"}]"}

Comment: @Kalhan.Toress I have initialised the state to const [allProjects, setAllProjects] = useState([]);

Comment: @deepakmurthy are you sure `result`  in `setAllProjects(result);` working correctly?

Comment: @Kalhan.Toress i get this {{id: 12345, name:"project name", responsibilities: "[{"role":"manager","name":"Test"}, {"role":"manager","name":"Test 12"}]"} when i do console.log(result); which is setAllProjects(results);

Comment: what am i missing ?

Comment: @deepakmurthy You missed to spell this correctly `allProjects.responsibilites.map....` it should be `responsibilities` as per the console.log :) and your second map should be `value.responsibilites.map((value)` isn't it?

Comment: sorry for the typo -- map is not a function - project.responsibilities.map is not a function

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the `result` as string as you've stored the data into database as string.

**What's happening:**

1. Frist you have the `.map()` method as the initial state is an empty Array `[]`
2. And then when you're re-setting the state with `setAllProjects(result)`, a string is being set which does not have `.map()` method. Hence you're getting the error!

**Solution:**

So you've to first parse the JSON with `JSON.parse(result)` while setting it to the state.

```
useEffect(() => {
    ... Axios.get ... other code
    setAllProjects(JSON.parse(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your setup looks great!

You just need to account for state not having any data while the API call is being made. You can return null/loader etc in this case.

Also make sure that you don’t set state until the API call is complete.

You also have a bug in your mapping - try this instead (also note the correct spelling of “responsibilities”):

```
return (
    ... other code
    {allProjects?.map((project) => {
        ... other codes
        JSON.parse(project.responsibilities)?.map((responsibility) => {
            return(
                <p>{responsibility.role}</p>
            )
        })}
```

Comment: const [allProjects, setAllProjects] = useState([]); this is my initial state

Comment: Exactly - allProjects.responsibilities is undefined.

Comment: what am i missing ?

Comment: You’re missing a condition that checks if the array has data before doing the mapping. You can return null if it doesn’t have data otherwise return the mapping you currently have.

Comment: allProjects.responsibilites && allProjects.responsibilites.map not able to see the data

Comment: So you probably aren’t waiting for the API call to finish before setting state. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/53332321/4722345

Comment: nope. can help me how wait for the api call to finish ? i have allProjects.title which is accessible but allProjects.responsibilites is not accessible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229491/discussion-between-jballin-and-deepak-murthy).

Comment: have joined and changed the code to wait for the API call to finish

Answer (score 0):

First you have to check if allProjects has value or not, if so, you will call map method. Here is when allProjects = [] already called the map method => error: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined