# Promise resolving function returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, state, fetch-api

I wrote a util wrapper for an API I'd like to consume. The wrapper handles request buidling and token fetching.

import refreshToken from './refreshToken'

```
/**
 * Fetch util handles errors, tokens and request building for the wrapped API calls
 * @param {string} url Request URL e.g. /chargehistory
 * @param {string} requestMethod Request Method [GET, POST, PUT, DELETE]
 * @param {object} requestBody Request Body as JSON object
 * @param {object} retryFn The caller function as object reference to retry
 * @private This function is only used as util in this class
 * @async
 */
const fetchUtil = (url, requestMethod, requestBody, retryFn) => {
    // Block thread if the token needs to be refetched
    if(sessionStorage.getItem('token') == null || Number(sessionStorage.getItem('token_expiration')) < new Date().getTime()) {
        refreshToken()
    }        

    let request = {
        method: requestMethod,
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${sessionStorage.getItem('token')}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }
    if(requestMethod === 'POST' || requestMethod === 'PUT') {
        request.body = JSON.stringify(requestBody)
    }

    fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}${url}`, request)
    .then(response => {
        if(response.ok) {
            return response.json()
        } else if(response.status === 401) {
            refreshToken().then(() => retryFn())
        } else {
            console.error(`Error on fetching data from API: ${response.status}, ${response.text}`)
        }
    })
    .then(json => {
        console.log(json)
        return json
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error))
}
```

This works and prints some json to the console once it is resolved. Next I built functions to consume utilize this abstraction:

```
/**
 * Get a list of all completed charge sessions accessible by the current user matching the filter options.
 */
const getChargehistory = (installationId) => {
    console.log(fetchUtil(`/chargehistory?options.installationId=${installationId}`, 'GET', {}, getChargehistory))
}
```

Which prints `undefined` I can somewhat understand that although I did expect a function reference or a promise.
I tried adding `async` before the fetchUtil and the caller and `await` the fetchUtil. This gave me an error to not calling await on undefined. I also tried reweriting it into a hook which did not work at all.
I would need the data in the `useEffect` hook of a component:

```
const Cockpit = () => {
    const { t } = useTranslation()
    const [chargehistory, setChargehistory] = useState(undefined)
    const [installationreport, setInstallationreport] = useState(undefined)

    useEffect(() => {
        setChargehistory(getChargehistory)
        setInstallationreport(getInstallationreport)
    }, [])
}
```

Why am I getting `undefined` and how can I resolve this?

Comment: Inside `fetchUtil` function, you need a return keyword before `fetch`: `return fetch(...)`. Also note that you should either handle the error inside `fetchUtil` function or just throw the error to allow calling code to catch and handle the error. Personally, i would remove the `catch` method call from `fetchUtil` function and chain a `catch` method wherever `fetchUtil` function is called.

Comment: Another solution would be to add a simple callback function as an argument and calling that instead of returning in the last `then` function of the promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `fetchUtil` function, it ends with no return value, which means your `fetchUtil` function is going to implicitly return `undefined`.

You said

```
fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}${url}`, request)
    .then(response => {
        if(response.ok) {
            return response.json()
        } else if(response.status === 401) {
            refreshToken().then(() => retryFn())
        } else {
            console.error(`Error on fetching data from API: ${response.status}, ${response.text}`)
        }
    })
    .then(json => {
        console.log(json) // (1) 
        return json
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error))
```

inside this function, `(1)` part works well, right?

I think if you change your code like below it would work.

First, update your `fetchUtil` code like this. Return fetch.

```
const fetchUtil = (url, requestMethod, requestBody, retryFn) => {
    // Block thread if the token needs to be refetched
    if(sessionStorage.getItem('token') == null || Number(sessionStorage.getItem('token_expiration')) < new Date().getTime()) {
        refreshToken()
    }        

    let request = {
        method: requestMethod,
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${sessionStorage.getItem('token')}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }
    if(requestMethod === 'POST' || requestMethod === 'PUT') {
        request.body = JSON.stringify(requestBody)
    }

    // return fetch here! it will return a promise object. 
    return fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}${url}`, request)
    .then(response => {
        if(response.ok) {
            return response.json()
        } else if(response.status === 401) {
            refreshToken().then(() => retryFn())
        } else {
            console.error(`Error on fetching data from API: ${response.status}, ${response.text}`)
        }
    })
    .then(json => {
        console.log(json)
        return json
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error))
}
```

Second, update your `getChargehistory` like this.

```
const getChargehistory = async (installationId) => {
    const result =  await fetchUtil(`/chargehistory?options.installationId=${installationId}`, 'GET', {}, getChargehistory)
    console.log(result);
}
```

Because I don't have full access to your code, there still might be errors left, but I hope this helps!

Comment: That does resolve the issue in getChargehistory(installationId), but it does not resolve the issue that now there is a result pending in the component tree after useEffect()

Comment: Do you mean `setChargehistory(getChargehistory)` part doesn't work?
If yes, it is because `getChargehistory` itself returns promise object as pending status. I think if you want to set the result with `setChargehistory`, you have to do it inside `getChargehistory` function. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332321/react-hook-warnings-for-async-function-in-useeffect-useeffect-function-must-ret) might help!