# How to use await keyword in useEffect() React Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to call an several async functions in `useEffect)`, but I am not sure how to include the `await` keyword to await their results

```
// somewhere else func1 and func2 are defined
async function func1() {...};
async function func2() {...};


// func1, func2 are imported into file of functional Component
...
useEffect(() => {
    async function foo() {
        func1();
    };
    async function bar() {
        func2();
    }
    if (...) {
        await Promise.all([foo(), bar()]);
        ...
    }
    ...
}, [])
...
```

This gives me

> Unexpected reserved word 'await'

How to `await` async functions in `useEffect()`?

Comment: While @CertainPerformance chose the most obvious duplicate candidate, in this case, [`useEffect` can't take an async function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53332321/1218980), and a little trick must be used, which is [highlighted in Shubham Khatri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66585259/1218980).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an anonymous function within useEffect and make it async likee

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function foo() {
        func1();
    };
    async function bar() {
        func2();
    }
    (async function() {
       if (...) {
           await Promise.all([foo(), bar()]);
           ...
        }
       ...
    
    })();
    
}, []);
```

or in a more cleaner manner

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function foo() {
        func1();
    };
    async function bar() {
        func2();
    }
    async function execute() {
       if (...) {
           await Promise.all([foo(), bar()]);
           ...
        }
       ... 
       // any code that you would have normally added 
       // in useEffect callback will now be a part of execute function
    }
    execute();
    
}, [])
```

Comment: that doesn't work, `execute` is not awaited in that snippet

Comment: @andi2.2 execute doesn't need to be awaited. Any logical code will bee written in execute and the lines of code written after await Promise.all will wait till promise is resolveed. Also you cannot make the callback of useEffect async

Comment: will, if there is code after `execute()` function call be awaited until `await Promise.all([foo(), bar()]);` is resolved?

Comment: @Stophface as I mentioned in my previous comment, all code thata you would put inside of useEffect callback will go in execute function in order to use async within useEffect

Answer (score -2):

This should to the trick:

```
// somewhere else func1 and func2 are defined
async function func1() {...};
async function func2() {...};


// func1, func2 are imported into file of functional Component
...
useEffect(async () => {
    async function foo() {
        await func1();
    };
    async function bar() {
        await func2();
    }
    if (...) {
        await Promise.all([foo(), bar()]);
        ...
    }
    ...
}, [])
...
```

Edit: You also can use `func1()` and `func2()` directly:

```
...
useEffect(async () => {
    if (...) {
        await Promise.all([func1(), func2()]);
        ...
    }
    ...
}, [])
...
```