# Calling a function containing axios.get() from useEffect(): 'await' syntax error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In order to avoid `.then(..)` I'm using `await`. I'm calling a function which contains an Axios call, returned as `response.data` after an `await`. My functional component has a `useEffect` which is supposed to set an initial variable based on the result of this function.

My error is: `Unexpected reserved word 'await'` . It requires an `async`, but where do I put that in my invocation of the function?

```
const fetchUserInfo = async () => {

    const url = 'http://myapp.com/getUserInfo/';    
    
    const response = await axios.get(url);
    return response.data;
}

function App() {

  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({});

  // On initialization, fetch & set UserInfo
  useEffect(() => {    
      const result = await fetchUserInfo();   
      setUserInfo(result);
      alert('Completed useEffect init');
  }, []);

  return (..);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332321/react-hook-warnings-for-async-function-in-useeffect-useeffect-function-must-ret

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you have few choices here:

1. Get all logic inside the fetchUserInfo function and relocate fetchUserInfo function inside the App component so that it has access to state and can set the state. like this:

   ```
   function App() {

     const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({});

     const fetchUserInfo = async () => {
         const url = 'http://myapp.com/getUserInfo/';
         const response = await axios.get(url);
         setUserInfo(response.data);
         alert('Completed useEffect init');
     }

     useEffect(() => {    
         fetchUserInfo();
     }, []);

     return (..);
   }
   ```
2. You can define the function inside useEffect and call it there

   ```
   function App() {

     const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({});

     useEffect(() => {
         const fetchUserInfo = async () => {
             const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1";
             const response = await axios.get(url);
             setUserInfo(response.data);
             alert("Completed useEffect init");
         };

       fetchUserInfo();
     }, []); 

     return (..);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You can use IIFE function. I think it's best way to get your purpose

```
 useEffect(() => { 
   (async () => {
     const result = await fetchUserInfo();   
     setUserInfo(result);
     alert('Completed useEffect init');
   })() 
 }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should call

```
const result = await fetchUserInfo(); 
setUserInfo(result);
```

In another function with async that you will call in the useEffect.

Or juste simply do it in the fetchUserInfo instead of returning the result