# useReducer is not updating the sate with useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to fetch data using `useReducer` and `useEffect`
`getPeople` is a function that return the result from `https://swapi.dev/documentation#people`
when i console log `results` the data is fetching correctly but the state is not updated.

My functional component:

```
  export default function App () {
      const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialSate);
    
      useEffect(async () => {
        const { results } = await getPeople();
        dispatch({ type: FETCH_PEOPLE, payload: results });
      }, []);
    
      return (
        <>
          <GlobalStyles/>
          {state.loading
            ? <Loader size={'20px'} />
            : <>
          <Search></Search>
          <People />
          </>
          }
        </>
      );
    }
```

My reducer function:

```
export const reducer = (state = initialSate, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_PEOPLE:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        results: action.payload,
        counter: state.counter
      };
    case INCREMENT_COUNTER:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
        counter: increment(state.counter)
      };
    case DECREMENT_COUNTER:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
        counter: decrement(state.counter)
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Did you try to log action inside of the reducer?

Comment: Don't think this will solve it, but I know that you should put async function calls inside a local async funtion when calling them from useEffect. Look at this question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332321/react-hook-warnings-for-async-function-in-useeffect-useeffect-function-must-ret

Comment: @hellogoodnight yes and it contains payload:  array of 10

Comment: Where are you using the state? Show the code for the People component, which I assume uses this array please.

Comment: @hellogoodnight amazing question thank you my bad am using the `useEffect` in the wrong component Solved now thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR**;

You need to wrap the async action in an IIFE:

```
useEffect(() => {
    (async() => {
        const { results } = await getPeople();
        dispatch({ type: FETCH_PEOPLE, payload: results });
    })();
}, []);
```

**Details**:
If you do the OP version in typescript then it will give out an error like:

`Argument of type '() => Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EffectCallback'`

The `useEffect` hook expects a cleanup function to be returned (optionally). But if we go ahead with OP's version, the async function makes the callback function return a Promise instead.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about IIFEs. Why does this work but not the OPs code?

Comment: Solved i was using the effect in the wrong component MY BAD thank you

Comment: @hellogoodnight gave the explanation in the answer

Comment: or better yet, `getPeople().then(({ results }) => dispatch({ type: FETCH_PEOPLE, payload: results });)`. No need for async, problem solved.