# React/JS using useEffect to change state

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, state-machine

I am new to React and would like some help on how to use **useEffect()**. I have a state machine implemented with Reducer and want to use **useEffect()** to update the state.

I have such state machine as below. At default the state is set as **init** and after **sendEvent("INITIALIZE")** is called the state gets updated to **idle**. I want to do this process inside **useEffect()**.

[image]

But I have a function to be executed before calling **sendEvent("INITIALIZE")** so the order I want would look like this

1. if current state is "init" then call handleInitialize() and wait
   until it gets executed
2. handleInitialize() gets executed and returns a flag
3. check the flag and sendEvent("INITIALIZE")

So far I have the following code and it seems that useEffect() can't be an async function

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect() -a");

    if (currentState === "init"){      
      let flag =  handleInitialize();
      console.log("flag" + flag);
      if (flag){
        setInitialized(true);
        console.log("initialize event INITIALIZE");
        sendEvent("INITIALIZE")
      }
    }

    console.log("useEffect() -x");
  }, [currentState, sendEvent]);
```

I have taken a look at [React Hook Warnings for async function in useEffect: useEffect function must return a cleanup function or nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332321/react-hook-warnings-for-async-function-in-useeffect-useeffect-function-must-ret/53332372) .

I still see the problem even if I wrap this function with async. I tested with the following code

```
 useEffect(() => {
    console.log(AppName+":" +"useEffect() -a");

    async function update(){
      console.log(AppName+":" +"update() -a");

      try {
      if (currentState === "init"){      
        let flag =  await handleInitialize();
        console.log(AppName+":" +"flag" + flag);
        if (flag){
          setInitialized(true);
          console.log(AppName+":" +"initialized event INITIALIZE");
          sendEvent("INITIALIZE")
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {}
    console.log(AppName+":" +"update() -x");
  }

  update();

  console.log(AppName+":" +"useEffect() -x");
  }, [currentState, sendEvent]);
```

The print out for this is:

```
ExampleApp:EaxampleApp2: -a
ExampleApp.tsx:128 ExampleApp:switch statement:init
ExampleApp.tsx:94 ExampleApp:useEffect() -a
ExampleApp.tsx:97 ExampleApp:update() -a
ExampleApp.tsx:125 ExampleApp:useEffect() -x
ExampleApp.tsx:102 ExampleApp:flagtrue
ExampleApp.tsx:59 ExampleApp:EaxampleApp2: -a
ExampleApp.tsx:128 ExampleApp:switch statement:init
ExampleApp.tsx:105 ExampleApp:initialized event INITIALIZE
ExampleApp.tsx:59 ExampleApp:EaxampleApp2: -a
ExampleApp.tsx:128 ExampleApp:switch statement:idle
ExampleApp.tsx:120 ExampleApp:update() -x
ExampleApp.tsx:94
```

I expected to see this order but the output above prints **update() -x** after **useEffect() -x**

```
ExampleApp:useEffect() -a
ExampleApp.tsx:97 ExampleApp:update() -a
ExampleApp.tsx:120 ExampleApp:update() -x
ExampleApp.tsx:125 ExampleApp:useEffect() -x
```

Please let me know if there is a way to do this.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you add to your question the code sample where you tried `async` and `await`?

Comment: @jmargolisvt I have added the code sample that didn't work.

Comment: Whenever execution hits an `await`, control returns to the caller. Then at some point in the future after the async work is done, the code after the await will execute. So your `"useEffect() -x"` is supposed to come before `"update() -x"`.

Comment: Besides that confusion, it looks like you're executing your steps in the correct order, no?

Comment: @windowsill Thanks for the explanation. So there is no way to see "update() -x" before "useEffect() -x" ? This is a problem for me because I need to send an event such as "sendEvent("INITIALIZE")" before useEffect() id done :(

Comment: If you want to do something after an await, just put it after the await in the async function.