# Is there any need of async/await in useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, async-await, use-effect

I was working on a project and was using firestore database from Firebase. I want to fetch data from the database once the page is reloaded. So the below code is working fine even without async await. But I have studied that we need async/await while API/DATA calls, please help me if I am wrong?

```js
useEffect(() => {
      db.collection('database_mcq').onSnapshot(snapshot => { setMcq(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data())) })
      
  }, [])
```

Comment: async/await is very specific for asynchronous requests featuring so-called promises. As your code doesn't use promises, you just cannot use async/await in it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Hook Warnings for async function in useEffect: useEffect function must return a cleanup function or nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332321/react-hook-warnings-for-async-function-in-useeffect-useeffect-function-must-ret)

Comment: Given the way it is, it isn't

Answer (score 3):

It's not only unnecessary, it's also [forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332321/react-hook-warnings-for-async-function-in-useeffect-useeffect-function-must-ret) - if you try to use an async function, React will throw an error, because the only thing that can be returned from an effect callback should be a function or nothing at all (and not a Promise).

Instead, use `.then` - if you're using standard Promises - or use whatever other method the API you're using provides for interacting with asynchrony. In your case, `onSnapshot` is fulfilling that role - there's no need to do anything else special.

Even in standard JavaScript, there's no *requirement* to ever use `async`/`await`, since it's just syntax sugar over `.then`.

Comment: You can use async/await inside of an effect hook by creating an async function inside the hook and invoking the function just like in the example you linked.

Comment: @SeanW you can, but should you?

Comment: Depends - if you have a few dependent promises, chaining can be hard to follow in some situations.