# async inside useEffect react

Tags: reactjs, next.js

So I have a function to run async, so put async inside useEffect, in below is my code

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    const data = async () => {
      const data = await getAllVertification();
      if (!data.status) {
      } else {
        setAlldata(data.data);
        setLoadingAction([]);
        let tmp = [];
        for (const element of data.data) {
          tmp.push({ status: false });
        }
        setLoadingAction(tmp);
      }
    };

    data();
  }, [update]);
```

but got waning like this

```js
React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. 
To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
```

Can someone explain to me ?

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332321/react-hook-warnings-for-async-function-in-useeffect-useeffect-function-must-ret

Comment: What specifically is unclear about the error/warning?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to cancel the operations after `await` resolves when the component is unmounted. Here's one of the ways to do this.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let isSubscribed = true;
    const data = async () => {
      const data = await getAllVertification();
      if(isSubscribed) {
        if (!data.status) {
        } else {
          setAlldata(data.data);
          setLoadingAction([]);
          let tmp = [];
          for (const element of data.data) {
            tmp.push({ status: false });
          }
          setLoadingAction(tmp);
        }
      }
    };
    data();
    return () => (isSubscribed = false);
  }, [update]);
```

Answer (score 0):

rewriting you code to make it more clear:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const data = await getAllVertification();
      if (!data.status) {
      } else {
        setAlldata(data.data);
        setLoadingAction([]);
        let tmp = [];
        for (const element of data.data) {
          tmp.push({ status: false });
        }
        setLoadingAction(tmp);
      }
    };

    getData();
  }, [update]);
```

Here `getData` is an Async function which means that when you run it it returns a promise which will be executed at the end of the current event loop cycle.
You dont have to make `getData` though.
Try this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    getAllVertification().then(data => {
      if (!data.status) {
      } else {
        setAlldata(data.data);
        setLoadingAction([]);
        let tmp = [];
        for (const element of data.data) {
          tmp.push({ status: false });
        }
        setLoadingAction(tmp);
      }
    }
  }, [update]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a custom hook, we can do the following:

```
import { useAsyncEffect } from "use-async-effect2";

// ...

 useAsyncEffect(function*(){
      const data = yield getAllVertification();
      if (data.status) {
        setAlldata(data.data);
        let tmp = [];
        for (const element of data.data) { 
          tmp.push({ status: false }); // weird code
        }
        setLoadingAction(tmp);
      }
    };
  }, [update]);
```