# how yo use an async method inside useEffect() hook

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I need to fetch an api in an `useEffect()`. I tried to do it and it throws me the following error: `Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`

My code is the following:

-Api I need to fetch:

```
export const fetchMyApi = async (code) => {
  const { data } = await useQuery("data", () =>
    clientAPIs.getData(code)
  );
  return data;
};
```

-My `useEffect` code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    await fetchMyApi(values.code)
  }, [values]);
```

I have found many issues about this on internet but they all offer basically the same solution such as:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMyApi(values.code)
      .then((data) => {
        return data?.options;
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, [values]);
```

or

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let didCancel = false;
    async function fetch() {
      const result = await fetchMyApi(values.code);
      if (!didCancel) {
        console.log(result);
      }
    }
    fetch();
    return () => {
      didCancel = true;
    }; 
  }, [values]);
```

None of those works in my case. I am using **Nextjs** framework.

What should I try?

Comment: I am using this hook for all my async logic in React: https://github.com/corets/use-async

Comment: This is a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332321/react-hook-warnings-for-async-function-in-useeffect-useeffect-function-must-ret

Comment: It sounds like you might be calling a hook outside the body of a function component.

Comment: @dir have you read the question? that solution is the last I proposed but it does not work

Comment: Yes, I have read the question, there are many solutions on my linked question and you are certainly not the first person to ask "how can I use async in my useEffect"

Comment: If you remove `await` from `await fetchMyApi(values.code)` then your code should work fine. You can _call_ async code from an effect, but an effect cannot return a promise, which means you cannot use await in the synchronous flow of an effect.

Comment: @AlexWayne Thank you man, but I have already tried and it throws me the same error (unhandled in this case). Keep in mind that `clientAPIs.getData(code)` is an async method that calls an api with *code* as parameter. same error with `try-catch`..

Comment: Also, you cannot call a hook from an effect. What is `useQuery` here? That seems like a hook that calls other hooks. And if so it _must_ be called from the main functional component body and not from an effect. Looking at the `useAsync` hook you linked, it returns a bunch of functions to manage the async operations. So you'll want to call your hook at the root level, and then call those returned function from your effects.

Comment: useQuery is from `react-query`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

You are breaking the rules of hooks. Hooks are only valid when called while synchronously rendering a React component. An effect runs separately after a componenent renders. So you cannot call a hook from an effect.

And yes you are calling a hook from an effect because this effect:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    await fetchMyApi(values.code)
  }, [values]);
```

Calls the `fetchMyApi` function, which calls a hook:

```
await useQuery('data', () => /* ... */)
```

---

You are using react query incorrectly.

First make your `fetchMyApi` just do it's async task, and nothing else:

```
export const fetchMyApi = (code) => {
  return clientAPIs.getData(code)
};
```

Then call `useQuery` from the root of your functional component:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const { data } = useQuery('data', () => fetchMyApi('some code here'))
}
```

[The documentation](https://react-query.tanstack.com/overview) should take you the rest of the way from here