# Warning: An effect function must not return anything besides a function, which is used for clean-up

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

i cant find my mistake why should i use cleanup , and return anything when i am use useefect i just want to check if the user is logged in or not .. ?

```
useEffect(async () => {
    var item = await AsyncStorage.getItem("User");
    console.log(item);
    if (item == null || item == undefined) {
      props.navigation.navigate("Login");
    }
    else {
      var user = await JSON.parse(item);
      if(user.fullname=="admin"){
        props.navigation.navigate("AdminHP");
      }
      else{
        props.navigation.navigate("UserHP");
      }
    }
    console.log("effect");
    
  },[]);
```

Comment: You need to use try-catch, may be there is any error throw.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Hook Warnings for async function in useEffect: useEffect function must return a cleanup function or nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332321/react-hook-warnings-for-async-function-in-useeffect-useeffect-function-must-ret)

Comment: `useEffect(async () =>...` returns a promise. Move the code to a separat function and just call it in `useEffect( () => { checkAndRedirect() })`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function check() {
      var item = await AsyncStorage.getItem("User");
    console.log(item);
    if (item == null || item == undefined) {
      props.navigation.navigate("Login");
    }
    else {
      var user = await JSON.parse(item);
      if(user.fullname=="admin"){
        props.navigation.navigate("AdminHP");
      }
      else{
        props.navigation.navigate("UserHP");
      }
    }
    console.log("effect");
    }

    check()
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 9):

Though the answer provided by Emran Quedan is correct, It lacks an explanation, As martin has mentioned in the comment, the root issue is because React’s `useEffect` hook expects a cleanup function returned from its callback which is called when the component unmounts. Using an async function like

```
useEffect(async () => {

},[])
```

here will cause a bug because when  `async` callback function of the `useEffect` is called, Promise is returned instead of function. But the rule is that we should either return clean up function or nothing from the callback given to the `useEffect`,but async function by its property always return `Promise` which violates this rule. to solve the issue slightly elegant syntax is like

````
useEffect(() => {
 (async () => {

    //Put your logic here

  })();

  }, [])```

In the above syntax, `async` function is defined and immediately called.
````

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and from what I understand:

It is recommended that you do not send an async function as a direct callback of useEffect, but you can pass a callback that inside it you declare an async function

```
    useEffect(() => {
        async function func() {
            await method()
        }
    }, [])
```