# Using UseState in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to map the values of userIDs to listUserIds, and then use values of listUserIds as keys in listUser function. But it only show the last value. What did I go wrong?

```
function Search(props) {
var listUserIds = []
const [userIDs, setUserIDs] = useState([]);
useEffect( async() => {
    console.log('useEffect has been called!');
    await userService.getUserAll().then(response => {
        var listUser = response.data;
        listUser.forEach(element => {
            setUserIDs([element.id]);
        });
    })
    .finally()
  }, []);
  
Object.values(userIDs).forEach(x => listUserIds.push(x));
listUserIds.forEach(x => console.log(x));
const listUser = listUserIds.map((userId) =>
<div key={userId}>
    <ThumbnailAdmin id={userId} ></ThumbnailAdmin>
</div>
)
return (
    <div class="col-lg-9 mt-4 mt-lg-0" style={{marginLeft:"200px"}}>
        <div class="row" >
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="user-dashboard-info-box table-responsive mb-0 bg-white p-4 shadow-sm">
                    {listUser}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

}

Comment: In your `useEffect()` hook`setUserIDs([element.id]);` keeps overwriting the state value with current element. You should have instead something like `const ids = response.data.map(item => item.id); setUserIDs([...ids])`

Comment: or, in a single line, `setUserIDs([...response.data.map(item => item.id)])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the values like this. using map you can collect all the ids then you can update the state.

```
await userService.getUserAll().then(response => {
  var listUser = response.data;
  let ids = listUser.map(element => element.id);
  setUserIDs(ids);
})
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I figgured out the reason 

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it's only storing one single value lies in the following line:

```
  listUser.forEach(element => { setUserIDs([element.id]); });
```

Your userIDs list expect an array and you are in a loop setting a single item giving a new array (value inside square brackets).

To solve using your own code, just remove the forEach and pass the listUser as the value of the setUserIDs.

```
 setUserIDs(listUser);
```

If you want to improve a bit more, take a look the following code ignoring that I removed the service call and the ThumbnailAdmin to help other community members when checking your question in the future.

```
function Search() {
  const apiUrl = "https://610d402748beae001747b7ac.mockapi.io/v1/users",
  const [userIDs, setUserIDs] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadUserIDs() {
      fetch(apiUrl)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => setUserIDs(data.map((user) => user.id)));
    }

    loadUserIDs();
  }, [setUserIDs]);

  const renderIDs = () => {
    return userIDs.map((id) => (
      <div className='id-container'>
        <div className='id-item' id={`item_${id}`}>{id}</div>
      </div>
    ));
  };

  return (
    <div class="col-lg-9 mt-4 mt-lg-0" style={{ marginLeft: "200px" }}>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="user-dashboard-info-box table-responsive mb-0 bg-white p-4 shadow-sm">
            {renderIDs()}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**code review**: To prevent racing condition (useEffect and async function) I implemented the async function in a better way. Reference: [React Hook Warnings for async function in useEffect: useEffect function must return a cleanup function or nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332321/react-hook-warnings-for-async-function-in-useeffect-useeffect-function-must-ret)

It can also be an arrow function.

```
    (async () => {
      fetch(apiUrl)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => setUserIDs(data.map((user) => user.id)));
    })();
```

**just in time:** avoid as much as possible to pass empty array as the parameter of the useEffect.

React Explanation on how to useEffect works:

> "... If you pass an empty array ([]), the props and state inside the
> effect will always have their initial values. While passing [] as the
> second argument is closer to the familiar componentDidMount and
> componentWillUnmount mental model, there are usually better solutions
> to avoid re-running effects too often. Also, don’t forget that React
> defers running useEffect until after the browser has painted, so doing
> extra work is less of a problem.".

Source: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: you're very nice, honestly. Your guide did help me a lot @DanielSantana

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an array of id in `setUserIDs`:

```
setUserIDs(listUser.map((element) => element.id));
```

Comment: thanks for your guide, I figgured out the reason 