# Axios is not getting anything with useEffect() (React Js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios, use-effect

I'm trying to get some data from a Django API, with Axios, and when I use useEffect only once (call it with an empty array []), it's not getting any data. However, when I add the state where the response data is stored, it goes in an infinite loop and it's changing data every second. I know that calling a useEffect with an empty array calls it only one time, but it seems that it's not working. How can I manage to get the data only one time?

My code:

```js
function IdentificationStep(props) {

  const [predictions, setPrediction] = useState([]);
  const [loadingState, setLoadingState] = useState(true);
  const [getValue , SetValue] = useState(true)
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setLoadingState(false);
    }, 3000);
  }, []);


  const getPredictions = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get('/snake-image/prediction/'+(props.id))
    setPrediction(response.data)
  }

   useEffect(() => { getPredictions(); console.log(predictions); SetValue(false)}, [])
   //infinite loop when i track predictions state
   //useEffect(() => { getPredictions(); console.log(predictions); SetValue(false)}, [predictions])
```

I tried .then(), like boxdox proposed to me, but it still returns an empty array

```js
const getPredictions = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get('/snake-image/prediction/'+(props.id)).then(response => {
      setPrediction(response.data);
      console.log(predictions);
    })
    //setPrediction(response.data)
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I'm getting an empty array like this:
[image: empty response]

Thanks for the help, I solved it

The problem was that use effect was going on infinite loop. I just checked the length of my predictions state and then use if else block on the useeffect()

```js
useEffect(() => {
    async function getPredictions() {
      let response = await axios.get('/snake-image/prediction/'+(props.id));
      response = await response;
      setPrediction(response.data);
      setLoadingState(false);
      console.log(response.data);
    }


    if(predictions.length < 3)
    {
      getPredictions();
    console.log(predictions);
    }

    else{console.log("already done")}
    
  }, [predictions])
```

Comment: `getPredictions` returns a promise. you have to either await it, or use `.then`

Comment: used it but get the same result maybe im doing something wrong ??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53572588/10796932

Comment: In the future, when you solve your own question, please post your solution as an answer instead of editing your existing question.

Comment: Okaay , thanks for the tip

Answer (score 3):

As your `getPredictions` is an async function that's why you are not getting data in your useEffect. You can do it by declaring the function in your useEffect:

```
function IdentificationStep(props) {
  const [predictions, setPrediction] = useState([]);
  const [loadingState, setLoadingState] = useState(true);
  const [getValue, SetValue] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setLoadingState(false);
    }, 3000);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getPredictions = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get("/snake-image/prediction/" + props.id);
      setPrediction(response.data);
    };
    await getPredictions();
    console.log(predictions);
    SetValue(false);
  }, []);
}
```

Comment: `console.log(predictions);` would still log the *wrong* value. See the linked duplicate for reasons why.

Comment: i tried it its throwing an error , (Unexpected reserved word 'await'). on line 40 , even if the function is async ... dont know why ?

Comment: await doesn't work inside a regular function. you need to define the anonymous function passed to useEffect as async, but that will not work inside use effect.

Comment: @boxdox. That's also one method but we can do it like this also.
What you can do is put a loading state as `true` when you start fetching and when the data is fetched you can make that loading state `false` and based on the loading state you can render your predictions.