# API Query fetch works, doesn't return result though

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, use-effect

I am trying to fetch a value from an API useEffect:

```
useEffect(async() => {
    try {
      const result  = await getToken(urlSuffix);
      logger.log('returned')
      setToken(result);
    } catch (error) {
      logger.debug('ERROR: ', error);
      throw error;
    }
  }, [urlSuffix]);
```

The thing is, the token never gets returned by the function, but the fetching part works correctly (I am logging the token). Here is the api fetch:

```
export const getToken = async (
  urlSuffix
) => {
  try {
    const url = `https://api_url/api/v1/asset/${urlSuffix}`;
    const data = await fetch(url, {
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'X-Api-Key': API_KEY,
      },
      method: 'get',
      timeout: 5000, // 5 secs
    });

    const token = data?.data?.collection?.token;

    logger.debug('TOKEN: ', token);

    return token;
  } catch (error) {
    logger.debug('TOKEN FETCH ERROR');
  }
};
```

The `logger.debug` when fetching logs the correct token, but the `logger.log` in `useEffect` never logs that the results have returned. What is stopping `getToken` from returning `token`?

Comment: Try adding `logger.log('calling');` just before `const result = await getToken(urlSuffix);`. To me it looks like you must be calling `getToken()` from some place else.

Comment: @RockySims You're right. This isn't being called, but I just CMD+F searched my entire project and this is the only place the api fetch query is being called. How is that possible ?

Comment: Try adding `throw 'wtf';` right after `logger.debug('TOKEN: ', token);` and then in the browser console you can look at the error to see the stack trace which will tell you where `getToken()` is being called from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) as if it were [Axios](https://axios-http.com/) which it is not.

`fetch()` returns a promise that resolves with a [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object which does not have a `data` property. I think what you want in your `getToken()` function is this...

```js
export const getToken = async (urlSuffix) => {
  const url = `https://api_url/api/v1/asset/${urlSuffix}`;

  // FYI - fetch does not support timeouts
  const res = await fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'X-Api-Key': API_KEY,
    },
    method: 'GET',
  });

  if (!res.ok) {
    logger.debug('TOKEN FETCH ERROR');
    throw new Error(`${res.status}: ${await res.text()}`)
  }

  const data = await res.json() // parse the response stream as JSON
  const token = data.collection.token;

  logger.debug('TOKEN: ', token);

  return token;
}
```

You should also not pass an async function to `useEffect` as it breaks the [cleanup process](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup)

```js
useEffect(() => {
  getToken(urlSuffix).then(setToken)
}, [ urlSuffix ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that using a `try...catch` inside of `useEffect` is a bad practice ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332321/react-hook-warnings-for-async-function-in-useeffect-useeffect-function-must-ret)).

But it seems to me that you set your `async`/`await` correctly, so it really should work.

Try adding the `getToken` function to dependencies of your `useEffect` hook.

```js
useEffect(async() => {
    try {
      const result  = await getToken(urlSuffix);
      logger.log('returned')
      setToken(result);
    } catch (error) {
      logger.debug('ERROR: ', error);
      throw error;
    }
  }, [urlSuffix, getToken]);
```

Comment: taking out the try catch fixed my issue.

Comment: I think you missed the point of that post you linked. The `try..catch` isn't the problem, using an async function for the `useEffect` callback is

Comment: @kalculated there is literally no way that removing the `try..catch` fixes your issue

Comment: @Phil I also changed all my useEffects that used an async function - thanks for the answer and for helping me improve!