# How can I catch an unhandled promise rejection locally without 'await' or 'Promise.catch'

Tags: javascript, error-handling, promise

```
const asyncThrowSampleApiFunction = async () => {
  throw new Error('SOMETHING');
};

const MyComponent = (SomeApiFunction) => {
  try {
    SomeApiFunction();
  } catch (err) {
    handleMyError(err);
  }

  return ...;
};

const c = MyComponent(() => {
  asyncThrowSampleApiFunction();    // call async function without 'await' or 'Promise.catch'
});
```

Is there any way to catch an unhandled promise rejection without `Promise.catch` or `await`?

In `React.useEffect`, we often use `async` function call without `await` statement. And I want to handle possible asynchronous errors in `React.useEffect`.

So I want to catch an unhandled promise rejection, but I can only find a ***global*** way to catch these rejection types.

(e.g. `window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', ...);` )

I want to make my own `ErrorBoundary`. So I need to catch these rejections locally.

Is there any way to catch them?

Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you use `catch`?

Comment: you mean `Promise.catch`?

Comment: Yes, `promise.catch()`.

Comment: You most certainly can use `async` functions in `useEffect`, you just can't provide one as the callback. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53572588/283366)

Comment: `React.useEffect` can receive only synchronous EffectCallback. So I should use it like Phil's referenced answer (`useEffect(() => { async f = ANY_FUNC_DEF; f(); });`). But this promise `f()` has no catch method. I want to make an error boundary which can catch async exceptions if client mistakenly do not add an promise rejection handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I catch an unhandled promise rejection locally without 'await' or 'Promise.catch'

You must catch a rejected promise somewhere with either `.catch()`, with the second argument to `.then()` or by bracketing an `await` with a `try/catch`.  Those are your only three options.

So, technically if you're looking for something different than `await` or `.catch()`, you could use the second argument to `.then()` - though I suspect that's not really what you were asking for in which case, there are no other options.

Comment: only two options.... OK. I'm going to find other way to implement it. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Well ackshually.... `asyncFunc().then(success => { ... }, error => { ... })`. No `try..catch` and technically no `.catch()`

Comment: @Phil - OK, that's really just a different way of doing `.catch()`, but I'll add that to my answer for completeness.