# React UseEffect fetch not functioning

Tags: arrays, reactjs, fetch, use-effect

I have a service that returns an array of records in 'res'. Works great in my REACT components. I need to retrieve the same data in a function but I think my syntax is wrong as I get no data.

Here is the code for the service:
...

```
import axios from 'axios';
import * as myConstants from '../Services/User_API_Base_URL'
class UserService {
    getUsers(){
        return axios.get(myConstants.USER_API_BASE_URL + "users");
    }
}
export default new UserService()
```

...

Here is the code in a Component that works great:
...

```
componentDidMount= async (event)=>{
  UserService.getUsers().then((res) => {
        this.setState({ users: res.data});
    });  
  }
```

...

Here is the code in the Function that does not appear to get anything into 'datau'
...

```
const [datau, setDatau] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const doFetchuser = async () => {
      setDatau(UserService.getUsers())
    };
    doFetchuser();
  }, []);
```

...

Any help getting this to work would be greatly appreciated. I am just starting to get familiar with Functions\Hooks, etc.

Rob

Comment: async but no await?

Comment: `await UserService.getUser()`?

Comment: here's an example of async/await for a useEffect calling an API https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332321/react-hook-warnings-for-async-function-in-useeffect-useeffect-function-must-ret

Comment: No change. @Subrato Pattanaik

Comment: Please try replacing: `const doFetchuser = async () => { setDatau(UserService.getUsers()) };` with: `const doFetchuser = async () => { const res = await UserService.getUsers(); setDatau(res.data) };`. Or, this: `const doFetchuser = async () => { UserService.getUsers().then(res => setDatau(res.data)) };`

Comment: Bravo ...both approaches work ! @jsN00b

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @jsNOOb:

Here is the working code

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const doFetch = async () => { const res = await UserService.getUsers(); 
      setData(res.data) };
    doFetch();
  }, []);
```