# How to make notification appear in 4 seconds, but avoid it if state has changed

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to show notification message after 4 seconds when some state is invalid. But if during that 4 seconds it has changed and is valid now - I want to put condition in `setTimeout` that would check it. But the problem is that it still uses the first state value, not the changed one. One of my assumptions to fix it was making `setState` in the line before synchronous, but don't know how. Maybe any other ways to fix it?

```
useEffect(async () => {
      try {
        const snippetIndexResponse = await getSnippetIndex(
            //some params
        );
        if (snippetIndexResponse !== -1) {
          setSnippetIndex(snippetIndexResponse);
        } else {
          setSnippetIndex(null)
          setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(snippetIndex) <-- it logs only first state, instead wanted null 
            if(!snippetIndex) {
              openNotificationWithIcon(
                  "error",
                  "Invalid snippet selection",
                  "Snippet slice shouldn't tear code blocks. Please, try again."
              );
            }
          }, 4000)
        }
      } catch (err) {
        setSnippetIndex(null);
        openNotificationWithIcon("error", err.name, err.message);
      }
  }, [beginRow, endRow]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First You can not call useEffect callback as async method.

Second for your purpose you can act as below:

```js
let timeoutId = null;

useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
  if (timeoutId) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  }
try {
        const snippetIndexResponse = await getSnippetIndex(
            //some params
        );
        if (snippetIndexResponse !== -1) {
          setSnippetIndex(snippetIndexResponse);
        } else {
          setSnippetIndex(null)
          timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(snippetIndex) <-- it logs only first state, instead wanted null 
            if(!snippetIndex) {
              openNotificationWithIcon(
                  "error",
                  "Invalid snippet selection",
                  "Snippet slice shouldn't tear code blocks. Please, try again."
              );
            }
          }, 4000)
        }
      } catch (err) {
        setSnippetIndex(null);
        openNotificationWithIcon("error", err.name, err.message);
      }
  })();
      
  }, [beginRow, endRow]);
```

Comment: you sure he cannot call useeffect with async function?

Comment: @adirabargil Avoid using async directly on the useEffect() function. Instead, nest the async function inside the useEffect() and it. This answer has details/example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332321/react-hook-warnings-for-async-function-in-useeffect-useeffect-function-must-ret

Answer (score 1):

I think you could make the notification UI a component and pass the state in as a parameter. If the state changes the component will be destroyed and recreated.
And you can add the 4 second timer in useEffect() as well as cancel it in the 'return' of useEffect. If the timer fires, update some visibility flag.

Live typing this - so may contain some syntax errors...

```
cost myAlert = (isLoading) => {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = setIsVisible(false)

  useEffect(()=>{
    const timerId = setTimer, setIsVisible(true) when it goes off
    return ()=>{cancelTimer(timerId)}
  }, [isLoading, setIsVisible])

  if (!isLoading && !isVisible) return null

  if (isVisible) return (
    <> 
      // your ui
    </>
  )
}
```

You may want to useCallback on setTimer so it won't cause useEffect to fire if isLoading changes -- but I think this should get you close to the solution.