# Issues upgrading async componentDidMount() to async useEffect()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks, react-lifecycle

// **UPDATE:** *The issue was using the state immediately after setting it inside `useEffect()`. See my answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72134083/12719338) for details.*

I'm trying to upgrade one of my React app pages from class component to functional component with Hooks. However, I have some issues due to  some async functions.

The way the old page behaves is that in componentDidMount() some data is async fetched from the database and displayed. It works properly, `myName` and `myValue` are displayed correctly.

```
// OLD APPROACH - CLASS COMPONENT


    class MyPage extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    
        this.state = {
          myName: null,
          myValue: undefined,
        }
      }
    
      componentDidMount = async () => {
    
        try {
          const myName = await getNameFromDatabase();
          const myValue = await getValueFromDatabase();
    
    
          this.setState({ myName, myValue });
    
        } catch (error) {
          alert(
            "Some errors occured when fetching from DB"
          );
          console.error(error);
        }
      }
    
      render() {
    
        return (
          <div>
            <h1>{this.state.myName}</h1>
            <h1>{this.state.myValue}</h1>
          </div>
        )
    
      }
    
    export default MyPage
```

I tried to update the page by carefully following [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53572588/12719338).

```
// NEW APPROACH - FUNCTIONAL COMPONENT WITH HOOKS

    function MyPage() {
    
      const [myName, setMyName] = useState(null);
      const [myValue, setMyValue] = useState(undefined);
    
      useEffect(() => {
       
        async function fetchFromDatabase() {
         
          const myName = await getNameFromDatabase();
          const myValue = await getValueFromDatabase();
    
          setMyName(myName);
          setMyValue(myValue);
    
        }
    
        fetchFromDatabase();
      }, [])
    
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>{myName}</h1>
          <h1>{myValue}</h1>
        </div>
      )
    
    }
```

However, when I do this, they no longer get displayed. I supposed they remain "null" and "undefined". Apparently if I do a `console.log()`, they eventually get fetched, but only after the page is rendered without them, which is not what was happening in the first case.

**Why exactly is this happening? Why is it getting displayed correctly in the first case but not in the second? As far as I know, `useEffect()` does the same thing as `componentDidMount()`. Should I proceed another way if I wish to call async functions inside `useEffect()`?**

Comment: There is no `this.state` (there is no `this`, for one) in a function component.

Comment: @AKX Sorry, I updated the question. This is actually just some placeholder code for a more complex code I'm writing in order to make things easier to explain, but in the original code, for the functional component, inside the return() statement {myName} was rendered, not {this.state.myName} as I originally wrote. So this wasn't the issue.

Comment: With the edit I don't see any issue with the code. Are there now any error messages in the console? Did anything change in the `getNameFromDatabase` and `getValueFromDatabase` functions? Can you include a more reproducible code example?

Comment: If I do a console.log("The results is: " +myName) just before the return() statement, I get the following:  

>The result is null  

>The result is Andrew // whatever name I fetched from the DB  

Maybe it has something to do with the intermediary variables inside useEffect() being named the same as the state, as @stivluc suggested?

Comment: No, locally scoped variables can use the same name as variables in outer scopes. Are you saying that what is logged isn't what is being rendered?

Comment: It is logged, but only after the page is rendered with the default "null" value.

Comment: So it sounds like your DB functions aren't returning any values to update the state with? Is that what I'm understanding from your last comment?

Comment: This is what I was doing wrong, apparently it had nothing to do with async. The code in the original post is correct. It behaved like that because I used state variables inside useEffect() immediately after setting them there.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72134083/12719338

Answer (score 2):

The `useEffect` hook and state updates are fine. Function components are instanceless though, so the `this` is just undefined. Fix the render to just reference the state values directly.

It's also good practice to handle errors when working with asynchronous code.

```
function MyPage() {
  const [myName, setMyName] = useState(null);
  const [myValue, setMyValue] = useState(undefined);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchFromDatabase() {
      try {
        const myName = await getNameFromDatabase();
        const myValue = await getValueFromDatabase();

        setMyName(myName);
        setMyValue(myValue);
      } catch(error) {
        // handle any rejected Promises and thrown errors
      }
    }

    fetchFromDatabase();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{myName}</h1>
      <h1>{myValue}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question. This is actually just some placeholder code for a more complex code I'm writing in order to make things easier to explain, but in the original code, for the functional component, inside the return() statement {myName} was rendered, not {this.state.myName} as I originally wrote. So this wasn't the issue.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are giving the same name for your response as your useState(). Try using different names. Then, put just empty string into your useState() default value instead of null or undefined. Finally, you no longer need to use ***this*** but instead access directly the value. It should be something like this :

```
function MyPage() {

  const [myName, setMyName] = useState('');
  const [myValue, setMyValue] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
   
    async function fetchFromDatabase() {
     
      const name = await getNameFromDatabase();
      const value = await getValueFromDatabase();

  setMyName(name);
  setMyValue(value);

}

fetchFromDatabase();
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{myName}</h1>
      <h1>{myValue}</h1>
    </div>
  )

}
```

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question. This is actually just some placeholder code for a more complex code I'm writing in order to make things easier to explain, but in the original code, for the functional component, inside the return() statement {myName} was rendered, not {this.state.myName} as I originally wrote. So this wasn't the issue.

However, I will try renaming the variables and if this is actually what causes the conflict.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function MyPage() {
  const [myName, setMyName] = useState(null);
  const [myValue, setMyValue] = useState(undefined);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const myName = await getNameFromDatabase();
      const myValue = await getValueFromDatabase();

      setMyName(myName);
      setMyValue(myValue);
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{myName}</h1>
      <h1>{myValue}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question. This is actually just some placeholder code for a more complex code I'm writing in order to make things easier to explain, but in the original code, for the functional component, inside the return() statement {myName} was rendered, not {this.state.myName} as I originally wrote. So this wasn't the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so **the code in the original post is correct**, as other remarked. However, it is a very simplified/abstract version of the actual code I'm working on.

What I was doing wrong is that **I was using the state in `useEffect()` immediately after setting it there.**

Something like that:

```
 // WRONG

    let fetchedName= getNameFromDatabase();
    setMyName(fetchedName);
    
    if(myName==="something") {
       setMyValue(1000);
    }
```

The conclusion is: **Never use the state immediately after setting it in `useEffect()` or `componentWillMount()`**, **use an intermediary variable.**

Instead do:

```
 // CORRECT

 let fetchedName= getNameFromDatabase();
    setMyName(fetchedName);
    
    if(fetchedName==="something") {
       setMyValue(1000);
    }
```

Comment: Affirmative. React state updates are enqueued and processed asynchronously. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately