# Is it possible to render/return React Native elements from functions?

Tags: react-native

so i want to load some data from my server using axios in React native. The data was retrieved successfully, but i don't know how to display it on the page. When i click button 'Load students' it does axios get method and after that calls method 'showStudents' but that method doesn't return anything. I really don't understand how rendering works in react native so i would appreciate any help and guidance. Also if there is easier way to do all of this, i'm open for suggestions.

```
export default function Students() {
const [s, setStudents] = useState('')

const getStudents = async () => {
    try{
        const {data: {students}} = await axios.get('http://192.168.1.2:3000/api/v1/students')
        setStudents(students)
        //console.log(students)
        showStudents()
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log(error)
    }
}

const showStudents = () => {
    
    return( <ScrollView>
            {
                s.map((student) => (
                    <ListItem key={student._id} bottomDivider>
                        <ListItem.Content>
                            <ListItem.Title>{student.firstName}</ListItem.Title>
                            <ListItem.Subtitle>{student.index}</ListItem.Subtitle>
                        </ListItem.Content>
                    </ListItem>
                ))
            }
        </ScrollView>)
    
}


return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button title='Load students' color='green' onPress={getStudents}/>
    </View>
);
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `showStudents` returns a JSX component, but not inside of the `render` function of the component `Students`.

You can just create a new JSX component and use conditional rendering in order to render it whenever the state `s` (I would call it students) is not undefined and has a length strictly greater than zero.

```js
const [students, setStudents] = useState()

const getStudents = async () => {
    try{
        const {data: {students}} = await axios.get('http://192.168.1.2:3000/api/v1/students')
        setStudents(students)
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log(error)
    }
}

return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button title='Load students' color='green' onPress={getStudents}/>
        {
            students && students.length > 0 ? <ScrollView>
            {
                students.map((student) => (
                    <ListItem key={student._id} bottomDivider>
                        <ListItem.Content>
                            <ListItem.Title>{student.firstName}</ListItem.Title>
                            <ListItem.Subtitle>{student.index}</ListItem.Subtitle>
                        </ListItem.Content>
                    </ListItem>
                ))
            }
           </ScrollView> : null
        }
    </View>
);
```

We could create a new component to make things more structured. Let us introduce `StudentList`.

```js
export function StudentList({students}) {
    return <ScrollView>
            {
                students.map((student) => (
                    <ListItem key={student._id} bottomDivider>
                        <ListItem.Content>
                            <ListItem.Title>{student.firstName}</ListItem.Title>
                            <ListItem.Subtitle>{student.index}</ListItem.Subtitle>
                        </ListItem.Content>
                    </ListItem>
                ))
            }
           </ScrollView> 
}
```

Then, reuse this new component.

```js
const [students, setStudents] = useState()

const getStudents = async () => {
    try{
        const {data: {students}} = await axios.get('http://192.168.1.2:3000/api/v1/students')
        setStudents(students)
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log(error)
    }
}

return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button title='Load students' color='green' onPress={getStudents}/>
        {
            students && students.length > 0 ? <StudentList students={students} /> : null
        }
    </View>
);
```

Comment: Great, that works. Thank you so much for your help. Also another question regarding this, is there any way i could fetch data when i load this page without pressing the button? I read something about using useEffect method but if it's possible can you explain what that does?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Create an effect with an empty dependency array, then it will be called on mount of the component. Check the answers for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332321/react-hook-warnings-for-async-function-in-useeffect-useeffect-function-must-ret) to get an idea. But check the accepted answer, and do not use some third party lib as suggested by others.

Comment: I have tried using useEffect for the the question you've given me but when i open that page(i put log inside) is calls my fetch function infinite times. Is there any ways i can fix this?             `const getStudents = useCallback(async () => {
        try{
            const {data: {students}} = await axios.get('http://192.168.1.2:3000/api/v1/students')
            setStudents(students)
        }
        catch(error){
            console.log(error)
        }
    }, [students])

    useEffect(() => {  
        console.log('asd')
        getStudents()
    }, [getStudents])`

Comment: `students` from the axis response is unrelated to the `students` state. You need to remove `students` from the dependency array. Leave it empty: `React.useEffect(() => { .... setStudents(students) }, [])`

Comment: It fiexs that part, but what do i have to do to make it so that when i add/update a student in my database and get back on the page where it fetches all students again because there was a change. Again i read that dependency array has soemthing to do with that(maybe i'm wrong) but i tried every scenario i could think of and it doesn't work.

Comment: Use a focus effect for this scenario. Refetch on focus gain.