# I can't display the values via the useContext

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to React and I'm learning, through a simple example, how to use the useContext hook.

Let me briefly explain what I'm doing:

I'm retrieving data from jsonplaceholder and I want to pass the retrieved object, through useContext, to another component (therefore without using props).

The ***error*** I get is the following:

**'UsersContext' is not defined**

The code is the following:

**App.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, createContext } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  const UsersContext = createContext();

  useEffect(async () => {
    await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => setUsers(json))
  }, [])

  return (
    <UsersContext.Provider value={users}>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <ListUser />
    </UsersContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

**ListUser.js**

```
import ListUser1 from './ListUser1';

export default function ListUser(props) {
    return (
        <>
            <h1>Component ListUser</h1>
            <ListUser1 />
        </>
    )
}
```

**ListUser1.js**

```
import { useContext } from "react";

export default function ListUser1() {
    const users = useContext(UsersContext);
    return (
        <>
            <h1>Component ListUser1</h1>
            {
                users.map((user) =>
                    <h4>{user.name}</h4>)
            }
        </>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to export the context from the file it is defined in (`App.js` in your case) and import it in the file you are using it from `ListUser1.js`.

So your `App.js` could look like this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, createContext } from 'react';
import ListUser from './ListUser' // This import was missing too!

// Create and EXPORT the context here
export const UsersContext = createContext();

export default function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  // You can't pass an async function to useEffect (you don't need it anyway!)
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => setUsers(json))
  }, [])

  return (
    <UsersContext.Provider value={users}>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <ListUser />
    </UsersContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Finally, add this line to `ListUser1.js`:

```
import { UsersContext } from "./App";
```

Notes:

- Please note I also fixed your `useEffect` so it doesn't receive an `async` function.
- You have a working version of the code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-oskar-mh5m8m
- It's probably a better practice if you define your context in a separate file. This would avoid circular imports

Comment: Short answer is : Take your context declaration outside of your `App` component, else you can't import it and use it somewhere else.

Comment: Perfect. You have been very clear in your answer. I couldn't get a better answer. I want to ask you about async await in fetch. Do we use async and await in axios? when can we use async and await with data fetch?

Comment: @Sarah It's better if you open a new question for that. Just a note: I just made your useEffect handler synchronous as it's a valid solution in this specific case. If you want to use async/await inside useEffect, you have to do something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332321/react-hook-warnings-for-async-function-in-useeffect-useeffect-function-must-ret

Please, accept the answer if the solution works for you.