# useCallback with props variable: React Hook useCallback has a missing dependency: 'props'

Tags: reactjs

Originally I had a `useEffect` which referenced to an `async` function inside of it. The Effect's dependency is a `props` variable called `props.valueMap`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    let callerTypes: [] = props.valueMap.get("callerTypes");
    if (null === callerTypes || callerTypes.length === 0) {
        fetchCallerTypes();
    }
}, [props.valueMap]);

const fetchCallerTypes = async () => {
    await fetch("/api/lookup/caller-types")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            props.handleValueMapChange("callerTypes", data.options);
        })
}
```

I was getting the Lint warning

```
Line 28:8:  The 'fetchCallerTypes' function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook 
(at line 300) change on every render. Move it inside the useEffect callback. Alternatively, 
wrap the definition of 'fetchCallerTypes' in its own useCallback() Hook
```

So following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53572588/1005607) I rewrote the async function as `useCallback` with its own dependency of `props.valueMap` while the Effect's new dependency is the function name.

```
useEffect(() => {
    let callerTypes: [] = props.valueMap.get("callerTypes");
    if (null === callerTypes || callerTypes.length === 0) {
        fetchCallerTypes();
    }
}, [fetchCallerTypes]); // Note the Effect Dependency is the changing function

const fetchCallerTypes = useCallback(async () => {  // Rewritten with useCallback
    await fetch("/api/lookup/caller-types")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            props.handleValueMapChange("callerTypes", data.options);
        })
}, [props.valueMap]);
```

But now I'm getting

```
Line 37:5:  React Hook useCallback has a missing dependency: 'props'. 
Either include it or remove the dependency array. However, 'props' 
will change when *any* prop changes, so the preferred fix is to 
destructure the 'props' object outside of the useCallback call and 
refer to those specific props inside useCallback
```

Can anyone help? Why do I even need to include `props`? What's going on here?