# Unexpected Application Error! TypeError: destroy is not a function in react due to useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, deployment, material-ui

I am trying to swtich components/routes but will doing so I am getting an TypeError: destroy is not a function but when I refresh the browser the error is resolved.
I am getting destroy is not function in when i am trying to click on Archive or Trash or Notes in Dashboard.js in swipeable drawer
please help me...!

```
function Dashboard() {
    const [toggleDrawer, setToggleDrawer] = useState(false)
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(toggleDrawer);

    })
    const handleListItemClick = (text) => {
        const route = `${text.toLowerCase()}`
        navigate(route);
    };
 return (
        <>
            
            <Box>
                <AppBar >
                    <Toolbar >
                        <IconButton
                            onClick={() =>
                                setToggleDrawer(!toggleDrawer)
                            }
                        >
                            <MenuIcon />
                        </IconButton>
                        
                   
                    </Toolbar>
                </AppBar>
            </Box>

            <SwipeableDrawer
                open={toggleDrawer}
                onClose={() => setToggleDrawer(false)}
                
            >
                <Box>
                    <Typography>
                        <img/>
                    </Typography>
                    <List style={{ marginTop: "100px" }}>
                        {["Notes", "Archive", "Trash"].map((text, index) => (

                            <ListItem key={text} disablePadding>
                                <ListItemButton onClick={() =>
                                    handleListItemClick(text)}>
                                    <ListItemIcon>
                                        {index === 0 && <LightbulbOutlinedIcon />}
                                        {index === 1 && <NotificationsOutlinedIcon />}
                                        {index === 2 && <EditOutlinedIcon />}
                                        {index === 3 && <ArchiveOutlinedIcon />}
                                        {index === 4 && <DeleteOutlineOutlinedIcon />}
                                    </ListItemIcon>
                                    <ListItemText primary={text} />
                                </ListItemButton>
                            </ListItem>
                        ))}
                    </List>

                </Box>
            </SwipeableDrawer>
            <Outlet></Outlet>
        </>
    )
}

export default Dashboard
```

I am expecting a smooth transition to the next component /routes without typeerror

Comment: I guess your issue can comes because of async in useEffect
please check this article, try to remove it, maybe it will fix it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332321/react-hook-warnings-for-async-function-in-useeffect-useeffect-function-must-ret