# Google is not defined despite there already being an API keyed in

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps

I have no idea why it keeps saying google is not defined. Does anyone know the problem?

I already tried moving the script to the head and all but here is still no use.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 2,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(2.8,-187.3),
          mapTypeId: 'terrain'
        });
      }
      // Loop through the results array and place a marker for each
      // set of coordinates.
      function loop() {
        var lati=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("lat2"))
        console.log("Hi")
        console.log(lati)
        for (var i = 0; i < lati.length; i++) {
          var coords = lati[i]
          var latLng = {lat: (coords[0]), lng:(coords[1])};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map: map
          });
        }
      }
      loop()
    </script>
    <script async defer 
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=THEAPIKEY=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I wanted it to loop thru what I have in my local storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loading the Google Maps Javascript API asynchronously (with `async defer`).  The API won't be available (`google` will be undefined) until it finishes loading.  At that time it will run your callback function (`initMap`).

Descriptions in the API documentation:

- [Loading the Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API)
- [Synchronously loading the API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#sync)

Move the `loop` function call inside `initMap` (or load the API synchronously).

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/me85woay/)

**code snippet:** (note won't read localStorage due to sandboxing)

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  var map;

  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 2,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(2.8, -187.3),
      mapTypeId: 'terrain'
    });
    loop()
  }

  // Loop through the results array and place a marker for each
  // set of coordinates.
  function loop() {
    var lati = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("lat2"))
    console.log("Hi")
    console.log(lati)
    for (var i = 0; i < lati.length; i++) {
      var coords = lati[i]
      var latLng = {
        lat: (coords[0]),
        lng: (coords[1])
      };
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map
      });
    }
  }
</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

No.1) Your browser doesn't know what `google` is, because `google` variable will be defined in later script. Place your `<script>` with `initMap` functions etc. **after** the "google" script `<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js key=....&callback=initMap"> </script>`.

No.2) It might be beneficial to run your code after the page is completely loaded. You can use `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { //your code here })` or use libraries like jQuery to do it.

P.S. Be more careful with your API keys in general. Don't publish them

Comment: I've added  to the answer. You are basically dealing with [delayed execution of Google javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36909380/why-use-defer-with-google-maps-javascript) and your own code must run some time later.

Comment: If you use `callback=initMap` then you (probably) don't need what you described in point 2). Publishing an API key is also not an issue if the key is restricted properly. It can be found anyway on any website using the Google Maps API by viewing the source code. That's why you should always restrict your keys.